# Unsung Hero query on Data Explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer

Can someone make a query on Stack Exchange Data Explorer for users to track their progress on **Unsung Hero** badge? I mean, in some queries, I saw some input box for users to input custom data for queries. What I am telling is about a solution, where there is an input (what i said before) for users to input their **User ID** and fetch data based on that. Since Unsung Hero badge requires "Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total", is this possible with just a single query or need 2 separate queries for "Zero score accepted answers" and "Total number of answers" (both should not count or consider and must skip questions by the same user)?

I hope you got what I meant. I am not an expert in Data Explorer queries. Can someone take the challenge?

Thanks.

*I believe this will be really useful for our community.*

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56217/the-true-unsung-heros

Comment: @ChrisF how can we track our progress? Like the one I pointed in question?

Comment: I can't believe that I'm asking this on _Meta_, but what have you tried? Data explorer is there for people that want to run queries and mine interesting things. If you're having a problem using it, we'd love to help .. but where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry - I didn't realise the link was broken try this - http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6607/the-true-unsung-heros

Comment: Or there's this http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i - a search on the data explorer would have found it

Comment: @TimPost 'm sorry that I tried http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/74657/the-true-unsung-heros But dont know how to make use of it :(

Comment: You aren't having issues using the data explorer, just problems constructing a query. This is, in fact a programming question. You could try on SO if you hit a wall again, but the question must include what you have tried so far, beyond a link to a saved query. If you have problems using the explorer itself, we're happy to get to the bottom of that. But questions asking how to construct a query, even using data explorer (barring the context of reporting a bug) are really not appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks Tim Post♦ for the info and also for closing the question :)

Comment: @blasteralfred Not to discourage you from _playing_ with it. Once you fork a shared query and get it to do _what you want_ .. you'll spend a whole week without sleep completely sustained on instant noodle... wait, I think I need to go to bed now.

Comment: @blaster - How is this tracking "progress"? I would need about 50 more zero vote accepted answers to qualify. Hope I never get that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's already a query for this, with a "clever" title which might have misled you: [How unsung am I?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i)

Comment: Clearly should have been named "How heroic am I?"