# Provide more information for Unsung-Hero badge

Tags: discussion, support, badges, zero-score-badges

When we  click on **Unsung-Hero** badge, we see following information

> Unsung Hero    Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total.

Next comes list of other users (sorted by recent badge awarded date)

I would like to see list of "Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total." In addition to above generic information (similar to what is shown for  Popular Question Badge).

Comment: Have a look at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56217/the-true-unsung-heros.