# Find tags with few experts?

Tags: feature-request, tags

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56897/was-the-unsung-hero-a-bad-idea-to-implement#56924) says:

*"We have tags where there are few-to-no experts, which makes the chance of getting a semi-difficult question answered very low. This is a deficiency in StackOverflow which is worth addressing"*

I would like to know how I can find out tags which have few experts? I mean tags like where questions are asked but which often do not have satisfying answers?

**Many programmers of us have surely seen a lot of different technologies, and might also have some experience in technologies which are not widely-known.**

I think of a feature where I can **browse such "few-expert-tags"** and maybe find one where I think *"hey, I have some experience in that, maybe I can help!"*

Of course you could just add this tag as one of you favourite tags, but the idea behind this feature is that **you may have forgotten that you know something about this technology**, so you would not add it as favourite tag, too.

Comment: You should probably be able to query the data for unanswered questions per tag. Whether that is an indication of the presence or absence of "experts" remains to be seen. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries

Comment: [Tag badge statistics](http://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) could help here. A tag with relatively many questions but relatively few gold/silver tag badge holders would be the kind of tag you're after. [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) will have the necessary information available, I think

Comment: I would rather like a built-in feature than using the Data Explorer. This feature might be also helpful for other users and for the site as well, so it should be accessible easily, I think.

Comment: I'm working on a data explorer query for this, but here are some interim results: These tags have *thousands* of questions but as yet *no one* has qualified for even a *bronze* badge (which requires 100 upvotes over at least 20 non-CW answers): [tag:data] [tag:printing] [tag:login] [tag:web] [tag:upload]. That's probably not what you're after is it...

Answer (score 1):

On a manual level, you could cross reference with the [badges>>tags](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) list.

This shows which tags have lots of experts (based on there being lots of people who've answered lots of questions and got lots of votes for that tag and so been awarded the badges for it).

Obviously you need to have some common sense when using the list, as very narrowly scoped tags will have fewer questions, so fewer badges, but if you look at the tags for technologies (eg .net) it should give an idea as to how well covered SO has it.

And of course - if you're interested in a tag and its not in the list at all, it might be a good one to focus on (once you've checked that it has any questions attached to it that is).

Comment: I would like to avoid this manual crawling. In addition, tags where no badges have been awarded yet are not listed there - but these are the ones which would maybe need the most help.

Comment: I thought that about missing tags was implicit, but have explained it now. Its possible the only non-manual alternative might be mining the data site, and not everyone is familiar with that.

Comment: I extended my question to explain why I would rather like a "browse few expert tags" rather than the "add favourite tag" approach.