# Cheat for `Unsung hero` badge?

Tags: support, badges, ethics, zero-score-badges

Here's the description of the badge:

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total

Is it possible delete my answers with positive points, and then undelete them?
What will happen if delete and then undelete an accepted answer - will the "green thick" remain? Has anyone tried to cheat this way?

I won't try this but wondered if it's possible.

Comment: You can only delete 5 posts per day AFAIK

Comment: @Some: Neither of those two point out that you cannot delete accepted answers, making the whole question moot anyway....

Comment: @MartijnPieters A quote from [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57257/148672)  *FYI: you can't delete an accepted answer.*

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: ah, check. VTCed as a dupe of that question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all: you cannot yourself delete your answers that are marked as accepted:

[image: deleting accepted answer denied]

If you *do* delete a lot of answers, you'll first run into the rate limit: you can only delete 5 posts per day. Secondly, your account will automatically be flagged for moderator attention, and someone will come and investigate *why* you are deleting so many posts in a short time.

So you cannot reach the badge criteria by deleting accepted answers with a positive score *anyway*, and even if you could, you'd attract some close scrutiny, likely leading to some time in the penalty box and the badge revoked manually.

Comment: Curses, foiled again!

Comment: must admit that I never tried to delete accepted answer....

Comment: Also, even if he could delete the accepted answers, deleting and undeleteting wont reset the votes.

Comment: Also, if a mod deletes an accepted answer and undeletes it, the tick magically returns if the OP hasn't changed it iirc

Comment: Badges are not revoked manually that easily. Only a dev can do that, and as far as I can tell it's REALLY rare.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: From the [How do badges work FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work): *The Stack Exchange administration has stated repeatedly that "regular" badges never go away unless they were obtained by heinous cheating.* I'd say that if you were able to get a Unsung Hero badge by deletion, that'd qualify.