# Join me in Welcoming Valued Associate #843: Rosie

Tags: discussion, announcements, community-managers

I’m thrilled to be the first to introduce [Rosie](https://stackexchange.com/users/20728780/rosie), our new Manager on the Community Management team.

Rosie is joining us to be a part of the Community Operations team. In the past, she’s worked at places like Vimeo, and VHX. She lives in Queens with her fiancé having moved from Manhattan not that long ago.

She also lives with her special needs bunny rabbit, Victoria. Victoria is a mixed breed rescue that is part Netherlands Dwarf and part English Spot — she’s adorable with lots of grey spots.

[image: Rosie's bunny]

Rosie loves to volunteer with animal rescue groups in NYC. She loves helping animals who may have suffered from abuse or neglect to find homes where they'll be loved and spoiled. Rosie and her partner both have a big heart for animals and think they will always have rescue animals living with them.

She’s also a self-described theater nerd, she loves plays and musicals. Since the pandemic hit, she’s been attending live stream theater performances and has been asked to be a reader for one of her favorite non-profit theaters. In the past, she’s done some improv and some sketch comedy writing classes. She says that New York is a tough city to do theater for fun, there aren’t a lot of opportunities to do theater for fun because most companies are for professionals vs.hobbyists.

Rosie loves delivering experiences that bring community members together. She enjoys helping people to discover spaces where they feel welcome and valued. She feels that now more than ever people need those connections.

During the pandemic, she has found lots of entertainment in an initiative called “[Penpoloosa](https://penpalooza.com/).”  The program lets you exchange addresses with two other participants so you can correspond via snail mail. She has one penpal in Florida and one in Idaho and they’ve been writing back and forth throughout the pandemic. She’s also an avid cook, film buff, and board game enthusiast.

For Rosie’s first month, she’ll be joining the CMs in hands-on community work before transitioning to management. She’ll be learning and working side by side with the team; working with moderators, addressing escalations, and assisting community members in order to enable her to help the team grow and optimize for impact in the future.

Comment: Bunnies have ... some history ... here on meta. [To further prove my point, here is a picture of a bunny with a pancake on its head](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17363/50049). We need more bunnies these days. I, for one, am excited.

Comment: @TimPost I've seen that before, although it wasn't on SE and it had a caption of: "I have no idea what you're talking about... so here's a bunny with a pancake on its head."

Comment: I use it whenever I realize someone knows something that I don't ;)

Answer (score 51):

Thank you everyone for the warm welcome. To answer some of the questions you've posed:

*If you're an avid cook, which is awesome, what's your favorite thing to make/bake?*

My favorite dish to make is a Hungarian dish called chicken paprikash. It's the family recipe my great-grandmother brought with her when she moved from Hungary to the United States and it makes me think of my mom and grandma when I make it.

*Do you play chess and/or any musical instruments?*

Sadly no. I know the basics of chess, but wouldn't be able to keep up with an expert. I do enjoy trivia and strategy board games though. I used to play guitar and piano when I was in grade school, but haven't touched either in years.

*Apart from sounding like a cool person who likes animals and theater, does Rosie have any work experience that will help with the duties of the CM team?*

Great question. I've officially worked in community roles for almost a decade. My past experiences have included moderation, building onboarding programs, community events both in-person and virtual, content, running focus groups, collecting and executing feedback, and supervising teams.

I'm excited to be here.

Comment: Lets give her some more upvotes so she has a propper flair to display in the FAQ about the CM team.

Answer (score 21):

The second new hire in a week; great to see the Community Teams getting new <s>paws</s> hands. Welcome Rosie and good luck! And remember: [on the Internet, nobody knows you're a rabbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog).

Comment: Think they'll make a 3-peat?

Comment: Although on occasion you do have to confirm you're not a cat.

Comment: I think this is the 23th hire. Seeing Ayo was #820

Comment: I can confirm I'm not a cat or a rabbit. It is possible that I'm a Kookaburra though. ;)

Comment: @RobertLongson what happens if you're a cat (just curious)?

Answer (score 10):

Congrats and welcome, Rosie!  I totally share the feeling that people need those particular connections more nowadays, and I hope you'll deliver many of those experiences to the community.  I do have a question or two:

1. If you're an avid cook, which is awesome, what's your favorite thing to make/bake?
2. Do you play chess and/or any musical instruments?

Good luck at SE!

Answer (score 9):

I hope SE isn't planning on making Rosie the Guinea Pig of new features.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker. I had to read the announcement 4 times before understanding that Rosie is not the rabbit featured in the picture (which I confused for a Guinea Pig). I was honestly convinced SE had chosen to nominate the rabbit in the picture as valued associate #843 and give it a personality.

Comment: If it helps I am an L1 English speaker and it confused me too. I had to check it was not All Fools' Day.

Comment: If you're ok with a dog as a mod, why not a rabbit as a CM? :D

Answer (score 7):

Apart from sounding like a cool person who likes animals and theater, does Rosie have any work experience that will help with the duties of the CM team?

In case you think that this is harsh or snarky, the last [valued associate anouncement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360990/join-me-in-welcoming-valued-associate-820-shodipo-ayomide) had a section about previous work experience and online communities.

Answer (score 7):

Welcome Rosie!

**I look forward to the opportunity to get to know you, whether here on Meta.SE or in the various [chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=all&sort=active&host=mattermodeling.stackexchange.com)!**

I also find it quite impressive that in your 12 days of having an SE account, you've managed to ask/answer 11 questions across 4 different sites already! That's almost a 100% "days to posts" ratio and I like that!

Comment: Thank you so much for the warm welcome.

Answer (score 4):

What does it mean to be a **manager** on the **community manager** team? Will Rosie be the existing team's direct manager/boss? Will she come directly under Sara?

Also will Rosie have any focus for either Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network, or is it expected that she'll be across all sites?

Comment: As I understand - they're splitting up the CM team into 3 subteams. Presumably getting another manager means that (hopefully!) there's plans for expansion. Currently Juan is a Manager of Community Managers - so presumably she's sideways in the org chart to him.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Ah interesting. I hadn't heard about that yet. Any links about the split?

Comment: Down at community stratergy here https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/ . I think there's a bit more discussion all over meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360713/what-is-a-curator-what-is-the-curator-team for example

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Ah, I do remember seeing that.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You're correct, Rosie and I are indeed horizontally aligned. We'll both be serving the community with our respective teams in place.