# New Community Managers have no "staff" indicator in their profile

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, profile-page, stack-exchange-team

Since July 2019, [Employee profiles are now marked with a “Staff” indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331654/employee-profiles-are-now-marked-with-a-staff-indicator).

This worked well and people working for Stack Exchange back then indeed got the indicator, however looks like it stopped working at some point.

Both [Ayo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360990/join-me-in-welcoming-valued-associate-820-shodipo-ayomide) (started working at Stack Exchange a week ago) and [Rosie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361266/join-me-in-welcoming-valued-associate-843-rosie) (started working yesterday) have no staff indicator in their profiles. In case of Rosie it still might be some cache, but I doubt a whole week can be due to cache.

Can this please be fixed, or in case it's on purpose (I don't aspire to know why) can the decision please be reconsidered and staff indicator be given even to new employees? Having some with and some without is worse and more confusing than not having it at all, in my opinion.

Comment: Isnt the explanation that there is only one persona able to do this, and they are on sabbatical?

Comment: @Luuklag, Then SE Inc should update their processes to no longer be dependent on a single person.

Comment: @Luuklag Bart is correct, SE got more developers, with full access to whatever is needed. It's matter of just... doing it. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two new CM's now both have `staff` tags on their profile pages and have been modded across the network.

> regret the delay
> user account type now set
> for our new CMs

Comment: Shameless plug for a FR regarding the STAFF icon (Add it to the network profile as well): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331654/employee-profiles-are-now-marked-with-a-staff-indicator/331765#331765

Comment: @Luuklag this might be one of those "Looking simple to do, but much more complicated to actually implement" cases, as the stackexchange.com has different code base, which might be missing vital parts required to fetch the info required in order to show the indicator. Hopefully I'm wrong though. :)

Comment: True, the codebases are for the most part not shared. But in this case is very doable. Just never made it up on the priority list.

Comment: @YaakovEllis would be cool if you could bump it a few places up the priority ladder. Especially seeing most of the announcement articles of new employees link to their network profiles.