# New badge proposal: Accepted answer with negative votes

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes, badge-request

I've seen some accepted answers on Stack Overflow with negative votes, and the same happened to me yesterday: someone just downvoted my answer, and the OP accepted it without upvoting it.

Wouldn't be a good idea to have a badge for that? Perhaps a bronze one, and a one time thing.

**Edit**: I was taking a look at [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3296/156246), where TheTXI proposes the same, and most of the comments are correct. Perhaps the badge should be awarded only if the answer was already accepted with negative votes.

Comment: What good behavior would that be encouraging?

Comment: For those who are downvoting, please, leave a comment, so that I understand what is wrong with my question.

Comment: The usual case is that downvoted answers are bad. Why would you want to encourage accepting them?

Comment: @slhck yes, I think you're right. Perhaps I was just focusing on my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15355960/297114

Comment: @OscarMederos [Votes on meta are a bit different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).  People are likely downvoting to indicate that they disagree with the feature request and would not like to see it implemented.

Comment: @animuson I think you're correct, but... what about the `Tumbleweed` badge? See @AkiSuihkonen comment in @Servy answer.

Comment: @OscarMederos What negative behavior does that badge encourage?

Comment: Ok. I think it is definitely a bad idea `:)`

Comment: @animuson What good behavior is being encouraged by the `Unsung Hero` for example?

Comment: @BartoszKP Answering questions that aren't popular... Someone needs to do it.

Comment: @Seb Answers with 0 score are not necessarily the ones under unpopular questions. This trait is shared with, for example, controversial answers (number of negative votes == number of positive votes).

Comment: @BartoszKP You asked a question, I gave an answer. I haven't seen or given many controversial answers on SO. I have, however, been awarded that badge and so I know how to obtain it. Did my answer make you feel uncomfortable?  If so, why?

Comment: @Seb "uncomfortable"? Why would it O_o? Your answer is a good example, however I'm pointing out that the criterion catches also bad examples. "controversial" answer are only one example ([here are the first 100 examples of such answers so you can see them](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/664565)), answers to bad questions are another of these (usually they are ignored by the community, some people tend to downvote them to discourage answering to bad questions, but they are a minority).

Comment: Why should this only be awarded once? I like the idea of this badge and of it being bronze, but I don't see any reason at all that it should be awarded only once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have an answer that is both the accepted answer as well as downvotes it means that the community feels that the answer is *harmful*, even though it solves the OP's problem.  This, in my mind, is *much worse* than an answer that is just downvoted and not marked as accepted.  It means that the answer appears to work at first glance, but will cause significant problems due to reasons not apparent at first.

This is exactly what we *don't* want to have on this site.  Encouraging this *highly negative behavior* with a badge is harmful, not helpful.

Comment: Why there is in this case the badge _tumbleweed_?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen What negative behavior does that badge encourage?  It's more like a consolation prize for not getting any attention.  If the question was actually *bad* it would most likely get downvotes, not no votes.

Comment: It's consolation prize for having so bad title that it doesn't lure in any activity.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen If it was really that bad then it's rather likely someone would open it up to either fix it and/or downvote/flag/close/delete it.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: I think "Tumbleweed" is specifically addressed at new users (although anyone can get it): "Sorry, your question really is out there, isn't it a bummer that it hasn't gotten an answer yet! Here's a shiny bauble, stick around for a while!"

Comment: @JoshCaswell If they've stuck around for a week to get the badge, they're already not in that category ;)

Comment: @Servy: Hovering over your question for seven days, madly hitting "Refresh", doesn't really count as sticking around. :)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Was that meant to be a question?  Because yes, actually, it does count ;)

Comment: Coincidence is not causality; the community can be wrong.

Comment: @Seb That's not "coincidence" though.  Votes are not random.  Yes, the community can be wrong, but they're *much* more likely to be right, in aggregate, than the OP is.

Comment: Coincidence isn't necessarily *random*; sometimes what seems intuitive in the world of one language is wrong in the world of another language, and that intuition causes a bias. This seems to ring true for programming quite a lot, at least from my observations. In a world dominated mostly by Java and Javascript programmers, you're more likely to see bad advice voted on positively and good advice voted on negatively by the community if you watch the C questions.

Comment: @Seb But that's not *coincidence*.  Someone misunderstanding something, or applying knowledge of one language to another where it doesn't apply is someone making a mistake, but it's not *a coincidence*.  As I said, yes people do make mistake, and sometimes people do incorrectly evaluate the quality of an answer, but the community as a whole is still going to be *more likely* to be right than just the OP on the whole.  As to your specific example, no, I *wouldn't* say that the community improperly evaluates C posts in general; the C community has a lot of knowledgeable people voting on posts.