# Badge suggestion: Lonely traveler (10 questions with upvotes, no answers and more than 10% of total)

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

I have about 4-5 questions like that. Usually, they are complex questions in areas where quite a small percentage of people have expertise.

There were several cases when I was wondering whether it makes sense to write a question at all, because I was almost sure that I wouldn't get any answer.

I think it makes sense to introduce such a badge to encourage people to continue writing complex questions in rare areas.

Also, I want to point out the (kind-of) similarity of this proposed badge to the ["Unsung Hero" badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/badge-suggestion-unsung-hero-5-accepted-answers-with-no-votes).

Comment: Might be more apropos to compare this to [tumbleweed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/38/tumbleweed).

Comment: @dmckee: You are right.

Answer (score 7):

Seeking answers to one's problems should be the only encouragement that one needs.

If you need a badge to make yourself ask a question, then you really didn't have a problem that needed solving.

Comment: I would compare it in with the Tumbleweed badge. It's a badge that I'm not exactly happy to have (I'd much rather have the question answered) but I would classify it as a consolation; I can't have an answer, but at least I can have a shiny badge that helps me feel people are aware of my plight even if they can't help.

Answer (score 4):

I understand where you're coming from here but I think it would also incentivise posting meh questions in random, rarely used, tags in the hope that no one downvotes...

I agree that posting difficult questions should be encouraged but I think finding better ways of bringing them to other people's attention should be the goal. After all, it's all very well getting a badge but if no one ever answers the question it's fairly useless.

Comment: P.S. Are you sure [your unanswered questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A422080+answers%3A0+score%3A0) are as difficult as you think? Maybe you just haven't written as good or interesting a question as you believe? For instance, I know absolutely nothing about the subject but the answer to b) in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519303/where-the-information-for-network-connection-api-is-stored) is yes.

Comment: Complex is quite relative term. I use it for questions which require either a lot of experience to answer or a lot of research to do. Most of my unanswered questions are more research heavy (vs experience heavy).