# Best way to award credit when solution is *based on* another answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, community-wiki, attribution

I'm playing with solutions to [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619739/replacing-tokens-in-a-string-from-an-array) on SO. There are some great answers there, but no perfect ones (broken in a minor way, wrong after I clarified the question, or good but not ideal).

I want to award credit where it's due, but the final code will combine of one or more answers with my own tinkering. It looks like there are three options here:

1. Mark-as-answered with the best answer (and there *is* a best answer), edit the question with my solution.
2. Submit my own answer, upvote good answers.
3. Submit my own CW answer, upvote good answers.

What's the right choice? This probably comes up on all of the SO sites. When the final answer is *close to* one of the submitted answers, the asker should get a chance to wrap up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not edit one of the answers (the closest one) to have the most aspects of correctness, then award it to that person?

That way, you reward the "closest to correct" answerer, and the answer has been edited so it's all in one place.

And of *course* upvote every answer that was useful!

Comment: Well not everyone has enough rep to edit answers.

Comment: In that case, flag it for mod attention indicating what you want done to enable the accept.