# Proposal: suggest to upvote the answer when you check it as accepted

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, up-votes, accepted-answer

I like the fact that when you upvote an answer to your question, SO reminds you you could also mark is as accepted.

Wouldn't it be nice if the same would apply the other way around, i.e. if when clicking "accepeted" you would be reminded of the possibility to also upvote it?

I saw [other questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting) here on meta that suggest the cases in which an accepted answer isn't worth being upvoted are marginal (i.e. Not having enough upvotes left, the answer being correct but crappy in its form...) but it looks like the majority of the cases are simple lack of understanding of (or care for) the platform by the user.

Comment: @alex - don't really get the point, sorry. What is the passage of my question that makes you think I don't want people to choose whether they want or want not to upvote a question!?

Comment: +1. I just popped in to Meta here just to suggest this if it hadn't been suggested already. How is it that an answer could be the "best" one, or the "correct" answer, and it wasn't helpful? I would like to see accepted answers automatically upvoted.

Comment: I don't disagree with the thought behind this idea, but on the flip side the **Tenacious** badge is a fun one - it's the only badge I have that Jon Skeet doesn't! :)

Comment: +1 Yeah Tenacious and Unsung Hero are quite something to have :) yet, accepted answers are deserved to have an upvote followed by.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that new users are able to accept answers on their question, but they aren't able to upvote them. Which I [disagree with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/shouldnt-a-rep-less-newbie-at-least-be-able-to-upvote-a-good-answer-to-his-her-o).

Comment: It should be easy enough to show the message only if you have the upvote privilege.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it would be nice but accepting an answer nets you 15 rep and is more important to mark an answer accepted than to upvote it as well.

So I would say, nice to have but not important.

Comment: An accepted answer with 0 votes looks *weird* though.

Comment: he's saying that having it accepted *at all* is what matters

Comment: Aye mr banana, that is true.

Comment: Re: An accepted answer with 0 votes looks weird though .. I have 20 of those

Answer (score -1):

I agree. Also, on a related note, I've been popping over to the [tenacious badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/225/tenacious) and upvoting some of the better 0-score accepted answers for people who have earned the badge from time to time. Maybe others could follow suit?

Comment: Then they'll never get the unsung hero badge...