# Allow new users to vote on answers they've received

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, voting, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shouldn’t a rep-less newbie at least be able to upvote a good answer to his/her own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/shouldnt-a-rep-less-newbie-at-least-be-able-to-upvote-a-good-answer-to-his-her-o)

Voting requires 15 reputation.

I think that we should make an exception and allow voting on answers given to your own question.
Just like a new user can comment on his own questions and answers, he should also be able to upvote his answers.

Otherwise, it will encourage people to ignore questions by new users, especially on low-activity days, so that they can spend their time answering questions with a motivated voter.

It also seems unfair to the users that they cannot reward their answerers (**plural**)  ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230641/question-about-windows-events))

Comment: There are many other examples, but I can't find any off-hand.

Comment: @SLaks, you might want to rephrase your title - at present it sounds like you think they should be able to upvote answers they've given, rather than answers to questions they've asked.

Comment: It might be better to reword it as "vote on answers to their questions". The way it currently reads is though you want to allow users to be able to vote on the answers they post.

Comment: @Dominic: If people think that, they'll presumably read the question and understand correctly.  Can you think of a better title?

Comment: @SLaks - "Allow new users to vote on answers to questions they've asked"

Comment: Two up-votes. That's all it takes. Two up-votes, and they can vote on *anything* - answers to their own questions, answers to other people's questions, other people's questions... 
**See also:** http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/shouldnt-a-rep-less-newbie-at-least-be-able-to-upvote-a-good-answer-to-his-her-o

Comment: @shog9: I saw that, but it didn't reach a conclusion.

Comment: @SLaks: Well, my answer to both is the same - new users most certainly *can* reward answerers, as they can accept an answer.

Comment: @Shog9: As I tried to point out in the question, they can only accept _one_ answer.  See my example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230641/question-about-windows-events/2230662#2230662

Comment: @SLaks: Um... Of the two answers there, only one answers the question. Why should an answer that **fails to answer the question** get *anything?*

Comment: @Shog9: Because it helped the asker.

Comment: @SLaks: by answering a question he hadn't asked yet, and now will probably never ask. So the next person to search for an answer to this unasked question won't find it. And the next person to search for the question he *did* ask will have this confusingly irrelevant answer to ignore. Why should SO encourage such a thing?

Comment: Perhaps someone could query (SU preferably) to see how many users asked only 1 question and did not upvote, that way you could quantify how often this occurs

Comment: It's not like there is an upvote shortage - rather the reverse.

Comment: Well I for one have at least 7 answers that got accepted without any upvotes, apperently that user was not able to upvote me (or didn't care) even though the answer solved his problem.

Comment: @Ivo: FWIW, I consider an up-vote and an accept as a double bonus, and only award both for outstanding answers.  You should not expect that every accepted answer is also up-voted by the questioner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While this sounds like a good idea, it is vulnerable to sockpuppeting and other abuse. Consider: two new users join the site. Each post a question, and then answer each other's question. Upvotes for all!

The current system forces the new user to post an answer that is regarded as useful by someone who isn't fresh out of the gate. 15 rep is a very low barrier as it is. It should almost be higher.

Comment: implementing this request would likely destroy the entire reputation system. So.. yeah. declined.

Comment: The current system is just as liable to sockpuppery.  Want to be able to vote?  Create two accounts, puppet and wantrep.  Puppet post question, wantrep answers, accept answer.  Puppet now has 3 points and wantrep has 16.

Answer (score 7):

If I see a new user post a question or answer, and it's a good post, then I upvote it.  They then only need one other upvote to be able to vote themselves on SO.

It's a really, really low bar partially so that it's easy to 'grant' them this privilege.

This isn't pity - it's merely recognition of a good post coupled with being a new user.

Although I generally upvote good posts anyway, so it isn't that far from my normal pattern.

However, I do feel that users should be able to upvote on their own questions regardless of their reputation level, so this feature is something I'm all for.

Comment: Mainly due to my own frustration when I join a new stackexchange site.  When SO started these limits weren't in place, so I never experienced what a new user goes through until recently, and it's a huge pain.

Comment: I call it pity because I felt the same way you did when I hit these StackExchange sites, and I pity the new users.

Comment: @Lance: Wait... How is it "pity" if you're up-voting a good question? Do you not normally up-vote good questions? ...Or do you lower your standards for posts from new users?

Comment: @Shog9, I'm saying that I have the desire to upvote the new users so that they can upvote their answers (which may not be mine at all), __but__ I myself refuse to upvote the crappy questions; so I squelch the urge.  I just don't think we should tempt people like that.

Comment: @Lance: People up-vote for all kinds of stupid reasons, and frankly this seems minor compared to the "this question doesn't deserve -1 UPVOTE!" attitude. IMHO, the problem is that new users can up-vote *too quickly*, leading them to do so before they've had any time to become familiar with the site. StackExchange is another matter, but we're not discussing SE here.

Comment: Upvoting a question now only gives 5 points, so they'd need more than one other upvote.

Answer (score 2):

When new users can't upvote answers to their questions, it just encourages 'pity upvotes' because people want them to be able to vote on their answers.  Upvotes should be for quality questions, not to boost someone to a level of being able to do basic stuff (that should just be a consequence, not the reason).

Comment: I typically give an upvote to users who ask legitimate questions, even if it's a simple or duplicate question. I don't see it as "pity-voting," but more of a welcome-to-stackoverflow gesture.

Comment: @Lance: And that's good? Why?

Comment: @Slaks, my point is that it's not good; upvotes should be given for asking good questions, not just given to give someone rep.  If I want a new user to be able to upvote my answer then I have to give him an upvote first (along with someone else).  We shouldn't give the incentive just to hand out upvotes like candy.

Comment: That wasn't clear from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is addressing a *problem* with the way SO works. You suggest that people may be discouraged from answering new-users because new-users cannot upvote. That seems to ignore the fact that others can upvote, and new-users can accept. There is plenty of incentive to answer 1-rep users in my honest opinion.

Comment: It's some incentive, but not so much, especially on low-activity days when there aren't so many upvoters.

Comment: @SLaks: Your answer can be accepted instantly if it helps the OP. And your answer will be around for a long time, providing plenty of opportunity for others to upvote it later.

Comment: Yes, but that's true for any answer you give, and any other answer is more likely to be rewarded even if someone else comes along with a better answer.

Comment: @SLaks: Why is that *bad*? I don't really see much good about encouraging people to post mediocre answers.