# Allow upvote for <15 rep users on own questions

Tags: feature-request, up-votes, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow new users to vote on answers they've received](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38834/allow-new-users-to-vote-on-answers-theyve-received)

I finally figured out why I get so many 0-vote accepts (enough to get the Tenacious badge).

I never realized (though I knew at one time) that
**Users with less than 15 rep can't even upvote answers to their own question**.

Doesn't this just propagate the 0-vote accepts?

While I can see the logic to not letting <15 rep users vote on anything else, I can't see why they shouldn't be able to on answers to their own question.

How about we fix that?

Answer (score 10):

They can, however, *accept* an answer which is +15 (more than an upvote) and they get +2 rep.

There are a huge number of possible reputation exploits around allowing new users to vote, even "only on their own questions". Just put on your game theory hat for a minute and think like an evil user; it'd be trivial to ...

- create two (or more) throwaway accounts
- ask some meaningless question
- *immediately* upvote answer(s) to that question
- repeat multiple times to multiple answers on the question
- repeat on multiple questions

You instantly have two -- or many more -- accounts that can upvote and potentially do a lot more. From scratch.

edit: you can only vote with a registered account, though you *can* accept with a cookie- based account. Unregistered users can *never* vote on anything, ever.

(Remember that accepts can only be done once, and can only be done 15 minutes after asking; there's no such limitation on votes. Accepts are also quite public in that the question *owner* accepts, compared to votes which are anonymous.)

Comment: Yep, and I always throw an upvote their way to help them get a leg up, but I still end up with a lot of 0-vote accepts.  This last one he tried to upvote me but couldn't.

Comment: All Jeff's answer does is explain the method one uses to game the system; instead of upvotes, one uses accepts.

Comment: @carl accepts are public and one-shot per question (and, can't be accepted for 15 minutes after asking.. can only be changed 1 time per day.. etc). Votes are private and can be cast many times.

Comment: maybe then it would be good to limit <15s to one upvote per day. Hmmm. Anyway, it's clear you've thought much more about this than the vast majority if the people commenting on it.