# Bonus when answering questions asked by first time poster

Tags: discussion, questions

On stackoverflow i answered a lot of questions by people with a very low reputation. Basically, most of the questions were my answer is accepted but no upvote is given. This is usually because the poster hasn't the right to vote up yet.
Usually when your answer is accepted you get 25 points (15 for the accepted answer and 10 for the upvote), when you answer a question of a first time poster usually you only got 15.
This is to say that maybe the system should give a bonus to the user whose answer is the "first" accepted answer of another user.
I think that trying to answer questions of people who post for the first time is more difficult (because usually the question is not well formed, etc. etc.) and takes more time and patience than answering other question, but providing an answer to those question is fundamental to keep the site going, because a good answer "hooks" an user in.
For this reason i think that answering those questions should be encouraged

EDIT- this is exactly what i was trying to say: [Shadow upvotes on own question for newbie users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88924/shadow-upvotes-on-own-question-for-newbie-users)

Comment: I think the biggest problem with this idea is that it would encourage gaming - for example, creating new users to ask a question then posting answers with a real account. I'm sure this already happens, but the extra bonus points would further encourage (or at least reward) that behaviour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shadow upvotes on own question for newbie users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88924/shadow-upvotes-on-own-question-for-newbie-users)

Answer (score 7):

That's why we have the [`Tenacious`](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/225/tenacious) (silver) and [`Unsung Hero`](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero) (gold) badges.

> **Tenacious:** Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total.
>
> **Unsung Hero:** Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total.

It might be a lot harder for you to get now, since you already have 800+ answers and 10-25% of that is next to impossible.

However, generally speaking, I don't think we need more incentives than there already is. Answers should be given without much consideration to who's asking and what their accept rate is. I agree, it's human nature to not ignore those, but I don't think the system should codify these by offering incentives to these questions.

It sucks to answer such questions, and I too, [at one point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88924/shadow-upvotes-on-own-question-for-newbie-users) suggested some alternatives so that new users can give out upvotes to answers that helped (on their own posts only). In retrospect, I think that was a silly idea which only complicated things. Nevertheless, it took a while of answering questions to come to that realization. I hope you will too.

Comment: I've both of them, in fact!But it was not meant for me, it was just an idea (not a good one according to the downvotes)

Comment: I totally agree with your post, it was more or less what i meant, since you guys already discussed that i think that's the best thing to do!