# Hipster Badge Suggestion

Tags: discussion, badge-request

> I used *x* before it was popular.

Tag badges are created by the system when the first user reaches the bronze level for that particular tag. Why not give a "hipster" badge to the person that caused it to be created? Honestly, I think the *very first* person to hit a milestone in any given tag should have something to show for it.

The point of this is to incentivize people to answer questions in low-traffic tags. I don't see any badges that cover this. Josh Caswell mentioned Tenacious and Unsung Hero, but I thought those were meant to encourage helping new users who can't upvote, but can still accept.

Of course, comment/criticize away...

Comment: I don't understand the criteria you propose. The creator of [pink-elephants] gets "Hipster" when someone _else_ earns a bronze pink-elephants badge?

Comment: No, give it to the person who gained the 100 upvotes required to create the badge.

Comment: So it's basically just "first bronze badge in [pink-elephants]"?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Well it just sounds silly when you say it *that* way

Comment: I used to answer in the [pink-elephants] tag before it was cool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the thing you're interested in rewarding has already been covered.

First, by bronze badges themselves. The list on [a badge's page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/174/objective-c) is in order of acquisition, so the user who got the first one is already acknowledged, and she can flaunt her rank in the tag via her profile's About Me if she likes:

[image]

Getting another badge just because you got a badge doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

Second, for low-volume tags, we have [Tenacious](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/225/tenacious) and [Unsung Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero). I am fairly certain that I personally won those badges largely because of my answers in the rather niche [pyobjc](/questions/tagged/pyobjc). That's exactly what they're meant to reward.

Finally, aside from not really being necessary, there's a slight possibility of abuse, as Lance already mentioned: I could invent a plausible but useless tag and go around slapping it on questions I've answered. I'll end up with a pointless bronze badge, but also that sweet sweet Hipster badge.

Comment: Point 1) I didn't realize they were sorted by acquisition date, thanks! 2) Is that what they're supposed to incentivize? I have both, and work almost exclusively in [android] 3) Ah, I assumed the system would pick up something like that and smack you with something.

Comment: To clarify my response to 2): I thought it was to encourage people to help new users who may be able to accept, but not upvote

Comment: That's the idea behind it as far as I know, yes: [Was the unsung hero a bad idea to implement?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56906/)

Comment: For 3) it might be noticed, but it would be handled manually via flags and moderator intervention. And, if you made the tag plausible enough, and did it slowly enough, it likely would escape attention. On the other hand of course, if the tag is really plausible (i.e., useful), it's no longer abuse. It's a minor issue, but it exists.

Comment: Ah, I was basing my opinion for 2) on this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112141/212780

Comment: I see. If you're in a high-activity tag, I'd think you're likely to get at least one upvote from another user on your accepted answers. On the other hand, the questions may just be ones no one else is looking at based on title or something.

Comment: BoltClock sure will be happy you picked him :)

Comment: Well, even though [android] is high-volume, a ton of users there are brand new, so that probably explains my horrific amount of zero-score accepted.

Comment: @LoremIpsum: It was the only person I could remember off the top of my head having that in his profile.

Comment: Funnily enough, I had just closed [Evan Anderson's](http://serverfault.com/users/7200/evan-anderson) profile page... :)

Answer (score 9):

I see no point in a badge only one person (per tag) gets.
How does that incentivize anything?  It seems like it's as abuseable at the Taxonomist badge.

Comment: Only one person gets it *per tag*. For example, if I worked hard on a low-traffic tag that *nobody* has ever gotten 100 upvotes in, isn't that a good thing?

Comment: Yep, and you get the bronze badge for it.

Comment: Fair enough. I just thought it might drive more attention to slower tags. If all I wanted was a bronze badge, I could get one far more easily in Java or C++.

Comment: There probably are many reasons against the present badge-request, but I don't think this is one of them (see [Taxonomist](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist))

Answer (score 7):

That's so mainstream. Real hipsters get the Taxonomist badge - asking questions before the tag even exists.

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea, just not your particular implementation of it.  It's silly to award the badge to the very first person, especially since it would encourage abuse, as Lance said.

That said, it *could* be interesting to award a Hipster badge to, say, the first X people to achieve Y upvotes on a tag, spread across at least Z questions.

But of course this is just idle conversation since this is almost certain to be [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Comment: I agree that the particular implementation could be better, but I couldn't think of anything myself. Hence the discussion tag, rather than feature request.

Comment: Anyone know if it's possible to make admin tags show up as red in an answer, as above?