# Use a consistent style for tooltips

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, design, tooltips

This post is a spin-off of ["New round of UI updates... apparently"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349529/new-round-of-ui-updates-apparently-edits-in-close-banners-summary-tab-chang).

Recently we got new, differently styled tooltips, for all buttons displayed to the left of questions/answers (upvote, downvote, add to favorites, etc). It's the same tooltip style that was used for the <kbd>follow</kbd> button.

[image: buttons screenshot]

I propose following changes:

1. **Use consistent visual style for the tooltips.**

   Currently <kbd>edit</kbd>, <kbd>close</kbd>, and other buttons displayed below posts (Including the sorting of answers) use native tooltips, whereas <kbd>follow</kbd> and all buttons to the left of the questions/answers use the new custom tooltips, and the <kbd>cite</kbd> button (on sites where it appears) has no tooltip.

   Compare:

   [image: tooltip style comparsion]

   I suggest using a same style for all those tooltips.

2. **Use consistent capitalization and punctuation.**

   Messages in all the new tooltips start with a capital letter, and have a trailing period, except for <kbd>Accept answer</kbd> and <kbd>follow</kbd>, which don't have a trailing `.`.  Most of the old tooltips, on the other hand, are fully lowercase, and don't have a trailing `.`, except for <kbd>add a comment</kbd>.

   I suggest tweaking the messages to make them more consistent.

---

Also see: [Please add a delay to the hover tooltips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349530/please-add-a-delay-to-the-hover-tooltips)

Comment: Also, it would be more sensible if they used consistent markup, currently some are `<a>` elements and some are `<button>` elements.

Comment: I'd also note that using pseudo-tooltips, rather than normal `title` based tooltips present additional accessibility issues. While I haven't explored these pseudo-tooltips from an accessibility POV, I'd expect there to be significant problems. It's nearly certain that they won't be handled in the same way as would be expected for a normal tooltip.

Comment: @Makyen You might be interested in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute

Comment: Was first reported on [meta SO in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396760/10794031).

Comment: [Eh](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405372/13138080), apparently.  Damn.

Answer (score 5):

This is something we want to do but don’t have a timeline yet. Setting it to [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) for now.

Comment: I just noticed the same thing today, also the tooltips for the sort buttons of the answers uses an older design. Any update on when this will get updated?