# Inconsistent use of punctuation in newly introduced message on voting buttons

Tags: bug, voting, tooltips, spelling, action-buttons

Inconsistent use of punctuation in newly introduced message on voting buttons: sometimes ends with a period, sometimes not.

[image: tooltip of acceptance button]

[image: tooltip of voting button]

Comment: Perhaps the first one should read "You accepted this answer (click to undo).". However accepting a different answer will unaccept this one as well ... so that won't be strictly correct either ...

Comment: In any case the `;` looks weird, the whole phrase as is doesn't look correct ... although it passes a grammar check ....

Comment: Dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349532/use-a-consistent-style-for-tooltips?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that one is about what actual form the tooltips take. Some are the built in mechanism of the browser via the `title` attribute, some are the insta-showing ones through some JS library. This is about inconsistency in the message itself of one specific tooltip - the voting one.

Comment: @VLAZ I mention both those issues in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples referred in the question have been fixed. They no longer [end with a period](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#periods) (which I think is consistent with Stacks style guide) and the acceptance tooltip now also includes a timestamp. As seen in the screenshot:

[image: tooltips of voting and acceptance buttons]