# The mod page for editing close reason notices doesn't show the delete question button

Tags: bug, design, moderator-tools, close-reasons, post-notices

Today, I was in the interesting situation of closing my own meta question as off-topic (don't ask) and discovered that instead of the `Edit question` button I expected, there was only a `Delete question` button ([screen-grab of post notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn9Hi.png)). The absence of the edit button would appear to be because I closed it (though that's not [documented here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349479/681403)), but the delete button was somewhat unexpected as the (mod-only) page for editing these (`/admin/flags/site-specific-close-reasons`) doesn't show that button.

For reference, this is what's shown on the mod page (ignore the width; the mod page doesn't have a right sidebar):

[image: post notice as shown in the mod page]

Wheras this is what's shown when someone else closes your post:

[image]

This isn't a big deal, but it would be better if the example for mods was accurate. We probably aren't in the business of having our questions closed often enough to make any necessary mental adjustment.