# Why are 15 points needed to vote?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are 15 reputation points required to upvote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/why-are-15-reputation-points-required-to-upvote)

Why is it so important to gather 15 points before starting voting in Stack Overflow?

Comment: (Please note how easy it was to have a much more useful title. Thanks.)

Comment: More or less the same as why you need to be of a certain age before being given political voting privilege

Comment: duplicates: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/why-are-15-reputation-points-required-to-upvote and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44046/why-require-reputation-to-rate-a-response

Answer (score 9):

There are many reasons.

One would be that it prevents people from making accounts to just up vote their own comments.

Basically the point limits for various actions serve to ensure that community members are participating in meaningful and helpful ways before being given the privilege to do that action.

Answer (score 4):

Voting up is just one of a number of [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) that you can earn As a SO member. It's one of the first and easiest privileges to earn — you can earn 20 rep points by getting two upvotes on questions or answers. Other privileges, like editing other people's questions or answers, require more trust, so you need more reputation before you're allowed to do them.

In short, you have to show at least a little interest in being a SO member before you get to vote.