# Why is the migration notice telling me this question came from the same community?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, per-site-meta, migration-notice

Okay, the title may be a little bit misleading - this is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). I know *why* it does this, but I can't say I like it.

See, when [a post is migrated from a main site to its meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229477), we still display this canned message on the finished migration:

> **migrated from <site> <timestamp>**
>   This question came from our site for <site subject>.

This is still the same community. I'm well aware that the sites are technically different (and the subject, too, is technically different between meta and main), but this is simply confusing and pointless.

Somebody posted to meta instead of main, or the other way around - their question got moved to the right section of the community. Now we have a message there, saying it came from a different site. Sure, it *technically* did, but this isn't an "outside" question, it didn't "come from" some faraway place - and that's exactly what I see in the visual cue of that notice: It's an outside question.

Personally, I'd prefer we'd just do away with all in-community migration notices, but I'd be fine with toning it down to a simple "migrated from <main/meta> <timestamp>" text somewhere instead of the full (pointlessly descriptive) block notice.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit better what problem this feature request resolves, other than alleviating your own personal discomfort?  An actual example would be nice, rather than the `Foo<T>` scenario you've provided.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, I mentioned the visual cue it gives. *I* do sometimes get confused when I see a migrated question, then read up on the box, and notice that it came from the very same community. I don't know if I'm alone on that, but the text is superfluous and implies a much starker difference between the site subjects than there actually is.

Comment: (That said, there might be more to the phrasing than I can quite pinpoint. I think the meta->main direction has a more obvious "this is *about* the other site!" phrasing, which the main->meta direction doesn't have.)

Comment: @FEichinger I think Robert is asking you to identify a specific question that was migrated in this manner.

Comment: @Joe Oh, sure. [Pick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41347/) [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229477). The migration banner is the same format as in all other migration cases, throughout the network.

Comment: @Joe Meh, I've added it. As I said, though, this is the standard format like everywhere else. I don't see an example as particularly important, since I've already quoted the format.

Comment: An example is important to show people what you're looking at.  Not all of us spend a lot of time looking at migrated posts.  Also, do you have an example of it working the other way around (meta -> main site)?  I can't find any.

Comment: Wait, are you talking also on per site meta? Stack Overflow and this Meta site are totally different sites at the moment, this is **NOT** the per-site meta for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm well aware of that. And, as I said, this [*also* happens on non-SO sites](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8585/).

Answer (score 1):

If it bugs you that much, ask a moderator to purge the migration history on it.

These are rare enough that I don't see the need to special-case them.