# Rep threshold for upvoting answers to your questions

Tags: discussion, voting, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shouldn't a rep-less newbie at least be able to upvote a good answer to his/her own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/shouldnt-a-rep-less-newbie-at-least-be-able-to-upvote-a-good-answer-to-his-her-o)

I've been told by a couple of 1-rep users that they can't upvote answers to their questions.  This seems strange, because a fundamental part of the site is upvoting good answers.  I understand that allowing upvoting on random answers by new users opens things up to gaming, but I would have expected that, like comments, you'd have carte blanche to interact with your own questions fully.

What's the rationale for this behaviour?

Comment: The threshold for the [upvote privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) is a mere 15, so not particularly prohibitive. Also, please be aware this has been [asked before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/shouldnt-a-rep-less-newbie-at-least-be-able-to-upvote-a-good-answer-to-his-her-o).

Comment: It doesn't make gaming any less likely just because it's your *own* question. They can still accept answers, though.

Comment: I was aware of the upvote threshold; 15 points is 3 upvotes on a question, which might not be "particularly prohibitive", but still an unnecessary obstacle.  Thanks for the link to the previous question, I couldn't find it in my searching before I asked.