# How do I solve conflict situation here?

Tags: support, not-constructive

Answers I want to describe a sad situation that I encountered here recently. I joined a subcommunity "Russian language" cause I am interested in linguistics and had some experience of working in a Russian language magazine as an editor.

So I posted some replies and got a comment that they are bad and too broad and pretty harsh commands in a style "*do this, don't do that*" from some of the old-timers here. Anyway I disagreed and said I was probably right and had some experience (maybe that was wrong to say). After that this guy started insulting me implying that I lie about my previous work and telling that his 4-year exp. here matters much more! Then we had a bit of unpleasant talk and later he deleted ALL his comments in it.

That was all a bit rude, but no problem, maybe my answer was a bit broad, I admit that. Bad things started later. He started putting minuses to all my answers (moreover 2 minuses at a time) and told me that he would do it further cause I "*don't understand in a good way*".

But I really wanted to take part in this community. I wrote to moderator using a standard form, but got no reply. (maybe he is a moderator himself?)

What should I do? I don't want to have all my answers minused (with 2 minuses at the same time - dunno why)
Here he threatens me to "control" all my answers - [Image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjFkf.png) (sorry it's in Russian)
Here he "controls" them - [Image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH9Hc.png)

Sorry about that question, I don't want to have quarrels or drama, just want to have friendlier attitude and not being minused cause someone dislike me personally. Whom should I contact about it if moderator option doesn't work?

Comment: You mention *minus score comments*. Do you mean *minus score **answers***?

Comment: Yes, I meant that, soz. Fixed.

Comment: Also, *. . .pretty harsh commands in a style "do this, don't do that". . .* I fail to see how that's being harsh. Maybe they wanted to explain the rules to you? (I don't know Russian)

Comment: Well, he has his right to say things even in a commanding tone, I can deal with that. But ater our talk he started to minusing all my answers. And threatened to do it in future saying "it's not hard for me". I see it as an abuse of his options based on personal attitude. So I'd like to know how to get an official answer.

Comment: How do you know he downvoted your answers? Did he say so?

Comment: Yes, he did. Later he deleted his comment with this, but I am pretty sure, admins have access to deleted comments.

Comment: @Firelord Ok, I got that.

Comment: @gnat Thank you. I was more saddened by the fact that he threatened to do it from now on.

Comment: consider asking for advice about this (or, better yet, asking for more general advice regarding quality of your posts) at [Russian Language meta](http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @well, all I wanted to get a moderator reaction. Of any kind..)

Comment: matters of content quality and users interaction is often more convenient to handle through meta discussion than with moderator. From what I have seen so far, it looks like your case is better fit for meta discussion. Keep in mind that moderators actively participate in meta (that's part of their job), so that you will most likely get a moderator reaction as a part of it

Comment: you lose two points when you get a downvote. I think this is causing what you call "two minuses at one time."

Answer (score 5):

There are two kinds of experience that are relevant here: experience in the subject matter of the site (in your case, the Russian language) and experience in the way stackexchange sites in general work, including the requirements for answers (which are not comments and not replies.) While you may have an excellent grasp of Russian, it's clear you're not totally "up to speed" on stackexchange norms, which may be causing you trouble.

Imagine I asked "how long does it take to get from [place 1] to [place 2] during rush hour?" and one person answered "everything takes longer at rush hour because there is more traffic." That is a correct statement, but it's not a useful answer. It's not specific and it doesn't give anyone what they need to make a decision or take action. It doesn't solve anyone's problem. So I would likely comment on an answer like that explaining that it's not a good answer. **This doesn't mean I think the content of the answer is factually wrong.** I think (I haven't seen the exchanges) that a similar thing has happened to you. You're providing answers that aren't good answers, even though they contain true sentences.

Take a look at other answers on the site, and at the comments from the person who is criticizing your answers. Could this be the issue? If so, edit your answers to improve them. Make them less broad, more applicable to the specific question being asked, and so on.

It's also possible you just ran into a rude know-it-all. Even so, they sometimes have a point hidden in their rudeness, so make really really sure that you have edited your answers to be as good as can be.

Then, and this step is important, stop arguing. The fact you have years of experience is not relevant. Your answer is right or not, useful or not. It doesn't become more right or more useful because you have more experience than the person saying it's not right or useful. It becomes more right or useful because you edit it to be more clear and helpful. Or it sits there, being as right as it already is, and not needing to be defended with external claims such as how much experience you have.

As you have probably noticed, arguing with people on the internet rarely changes anything. It just generally leaves a mess. Moderators often delete rude comments; you can speed that process up by flagging anything offensive. Replying doesn't usually make things better.

Comment: as far as I can tell, OP doesn't have sufficient reputation to comment over there. Consider [edit]ing the answer to account for that. FWIW two meta posts I find particularly useful in cases like this are [How does a lurker gain reputation to receive the privilege for commenting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164035/165773) and [Is it OK to use an “answer” to comment if you lack the reputation to comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265784/839601)

Comment: I wasn't suggesting the OP comment on anything. Simply clarifying that something can be a bad answer even if it's factually correct or true.

Comment: I see, you're right - there's no suggestion to comment in there