# Old unanswered question and new user

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, new-users, privileges

I found an old unanswered question on ServerFault.com that I would like to revive because I have the exact same issue.  However, my account is new and I do not yet have enough reputation to post a comment.

So here is my question:  do I post my plea for more information as an answer with the hope that it's flagged as trivial answer and converted to comment, or create a new question and provide a link to the old question?

I just don't want my question to get flagged as duplicate, nor do I want my "answer" to get downvoted due to not actually being an answer.

I did search and found [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164035/374170) - which is my plan B. But please be nice, this is my first Stack question.  Just like the guy in the thread I linked, I have been a long time reader of Stacks, just never felt the need to post until now.

Comment: Is your issue 100% the same as the dupe or do you have a chance to bring in a different context / requirement? Because that would enable you to say something like *My issue is very similar to [link] but in my case I also have to foo the bar...* in which case you can post a new question

Comment: I concede.  Servy is a better ninja than I at searching, and I should have tried harder before posting.  Thanks for the tip, rene.  I honestly tried to think how my question could have been different, but couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want attention for a specific question, another thing you can do is edit the post. This puts it at the top of the question list.

Be sure to make it a *good* edit. You can use [this list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338670/6388243) for ideas.

Alternatively, if you <s>sell your soul to me</s> ask *really* nicely, I'll use my association bonus to start a bounty on your behalf. But only if you ask nicely.

Comment: After 3 days of editing posts I can find and answering questions, I have 9 rep on ServerFault.com.  I could have tried harder, but I just got tied up with actual work stuff... pesky jobs, and all that.  I am ready to s̶e̶l̶l̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶s̶o̶u̶l̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ask really nicely to start a bounty on my behalf.  Here is the link to the question I want answered. https://serverfault.com/q/363514/442063 - sorry about the double post, but got stuck trying to find a way to put strike-through in comments then a phone call and timed out the edit.