# I want to chat with a specific user to ask them a question, how can I do that?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question to a specific user on Islam.SE, but I don't have the reputation to create or participate in chat.

How can I ask my question to this user?

Comment: I researched everything- Robert Harvey

Comment: I want to start a Q&A chat, thats it? It is a simple question, I don't understand.

Comment: @NewMember Is your question able to be posted as an actual question on a Stack?

Comment: It seems that I need a minimal of 2 upvotes. What can I do to required?

Comment: Yes- Rubikmoose

Comment: You see it's really difficult to answer these questions to help out those profiles and get some points, this is because most of the question on there is about this site. I am restricted, for some reason,  to only answer those questions? But how, I just joined, so therefore I can't and I do not know much about this site .

Comment: @NewMember why not just ask the question then? Also, if your question is one about how these sites work, in general, you can ask about that here.

Comment: Is the user you want to talk to here on Meta Stack Exchange, StackOverflow, Islam, or somewhere else? (BTW if you type `@` before a person's username you can notify them that you have responded in a comment.)

Comment: @NewMember What is your question? Give us a brief summary and we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: It was an Islamic question, directed to Medi1Saif ♦. I need to chat with this user, Q&A. They are great at answering Islamic questions, and I find them pretty dependable?

Comment: @NewMember If you have a question that is on-topic for Islam.SE, then you should ask it there as a question. Chat isn't for bypassing the question-asking process to target a single user with a request.

Comment: So, do I just join that community and ask the question there?-

Comment: @NewMember According to your profile, you are already a member of that community. Simply go to [ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on that site and type your question. User's will see it and you should get some good answers. If you are confused, look at Islam's [How to Ask](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) information.

Comment: You need 20, not 100. Also, typically you can't/shouldn't really expect a specific user to answer. Folks fo things when they have time. Also there's three chat servers, and SO, MSE and *everyone else* has their own.

Comment: *You see it's really difficult to answer these questions to help out those profiles and get some points* ... anyone can suggest good/quality edits to existing posts and each edit, once reviewed and approved gains you 2 reputation. So 10 suggested edits puts you at the chat privilege, 25 at the comment everywhere. Doable in a weekend. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164035/how-does-a-lurker-gain-reputation-to-receive-privilege-for-commenting

Comment: There's no workaround to chat, but by being an active member on the site be aware that if you had a question on Islam you should ask it on the main site of IslamSE. Don't rely on my answers I'm not an authority on Islam nor am I a know it all in the different topics of Islam. Once you ask a question there's a 90-99% chance that I might read it and hopefully leave a comment.

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Answer (score 11):

## Stack exchange is not a chat site

Here on meta the rules are a little different but fundamentally we are not a chat site. We are a Q&A site and privileges like chat are earned by creating quality questions and answers.

If your question is on-topic at one of the varies SE sites, go ahead and post it there. This does not require any reputation and if it is a good question, will help you earn other privileges.

If your question is a personal one that can only be answered by a single user, you are out of luck. That is not something this site is for. Even if you had access to chat you wouldn't be able to directly message another users unless they were also active in the same chat.

Basically, if you have a question, ask it as a question on the appropriate site. Don't worry about chat as that is not what the site is focused on.

Comment: Oh, I see. But like it needs a quality answer and I'm afraid If I post that question, all of you delete it.

Comment: @NewMember You need to post the question on the correct site and follow the guidelines for that site. The [help] on that site should be able to guide you to asking a good question. We don't just delete bad questions, we will help you make it into a good question, if you are willing to listen. And quality answers is what we do here. That's why we don't encourage chat, to focus on answers.

Comment: @NewMember You can also gain rep by making quality edits and having them approved.

Answer (score 6):

Ironically, your question shows a few good results from the site having chat be a rep-locked privilege and having no easy way to DM someone.

If you have a question that is on-topic for Islam.SE, then you should ask it there as a question. Chat isn't for bypassing the question-asking process to target a single user with a request. Nobody is going to help you work around the entire point of this site, if that is your intent. If you have a question, ask it the way the site wants you to. The person you are trying to reach is a moderator of that site, if you post a question, it seems likely that they'll see it.

When you have <20 rep you have no way to initiate or participate in chats on your own. The only exception is under your own Q/A.

The only way it's possible is if a mod or RO specifically whitelists you into a room. There's no good way that I'd recommend to contact one of those people however.

**The easiest way, is the intended way: by gaining rep.**

With 5 rep, you could simply comment on a post and ask your question (assuming it is relevant to their post). You can gain more than 5 rep by getting a single upvote on a Q or A that you post or from several approved edits.

With 20 rep, you could go to the site's main chatroom and see if you can ping them there (if you have 20 rep). Or combine it with a comment to see if that person is willing to create a room for you and them to talk which you can then join.

[image]