# What if Stack Exchange sites gave a provisional/initial reputation to new users?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

What if new users were given an initial rating of say, `300?` instead of just 1? Then, based on their good/bad contributions we could assess​ their "true" reputation. The benefit is that if there is an average new user(non spammer) it would take them a lot of energy and time to get to their "true" reputation i.e get the privileges they deserve, and many privileges (like commenting, voting, editing) are locked for new users as well; so a provisional reputation might solve this problem.
A question mark like in `300?` would tell that the reputation is provisional, so that others know that the user is new. The question mark would go away after user gets more than 10 up/down votes on their posts.

I got this idea while I was playing chess on [lichess.org](https://www.lichess.org), which initially gave me a provisional rating of `1500?`. I thought wouldn't this be a good idea for Stack Exchange?

More about provisional rating on Lichess [here](https://lichess.org/faq#provisional).

Comment: They already do, all users get 1 rep. " many privileges(like commenting or up-voting) are locked for new users too so a provisional reputation might solve this problem." That is not a problem, it is designed that way, SE could just give those privileges to everyone if they wanted to.

Comment: The site would need to fight massive spamming attacks.

Comment: Chess ranks and more generally Elo-based or motivated ranking systems are of an entirely different family than SE rep, I don't think it makes sense to use one to inform the other. SE rep for commenting and upvoting is just a low hurdle to say "we want comments and votes from accounts that have shown they can contribute *something* positive before they get that privilege".

Comment: If we automatically gave new users 300 rep, we would have to fear the fact that they would spam-flag everything and downvote everything and let them participate in the chat for free. We would then have to shift the privilege requirements fowards and recalculate everyone's rep, and that's *certainly* not worth all the trouble. I think a better idea is that there should be such a thing as a NEGATIVE amount of rep.

Comment: 300? No way! Maybe a starting rep of 30, so they can chat, and with a bit of effort they can also comment anywhere. But the main benefit to this idea is that newbies would be more affected by downvotes on poor questions; the current scheme makes them relatively immune to that (although of course they'll get rate-limited & question-banned if they continue to post low quality questions).

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just add negative rep scores?

Comment: So the starting reputation is increased to 300 reputations.  This would mean all requirements for privileges would have to be adjusted.  I have seen literally thousands of new users, submit answers, in order to submit commentary.  Giving them 300 reputations without adjusting that privilege will only lead to commentary that will be flagged and deleted by a moderator.  It takes 2 upvotes on any contribution in order to submit a comment.  **If you submit even the most trivial contribution that is possible.**

Comment: Easy solution! Give every new account 300 rep instead of 1. Give every existing member bonus 299 rep. Shift all privileges by 299 rep. Done!

Comment: imo SE's aim should be that every user who wants to contribute *can* contribute. Suppose if an average engineer were to join the site today. (s)he can't comment/vote they would have to come up with unique and good QA, before someone else does, to get those privileges. but with provisional rep the average users can contribute in *some* way(votes/comments/edits) right away to the site before making any content. For such "genuine" users a provisional rep might be a good idea.

Comment: As for spammers the "genuine" new users can handle them, assuming that they are more than the spammers.

Comment: see also: [How does lurker gain reputation to receive privilege for commenting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164035/165773)

Comment: This suggestion is just expending development effort on moving a baseline:(

Comment: Reputation is not so much a measure of proficiency, it's a measure of labor, how much somebody has invested in the platform. It makes sense to start at zero.

Answer (score 19):

There is no need to make it "easy" to get reputation. If a mediocre user, like myself, needs reputation they can take a dictionary and start suggesting edits on existing posts, or even better, tag wikis. Earns you +2 on every accepted edit and in a weekend I'm at +50. Now I can comment everywhere. Rinse / repeat a few weekends and you have access to the review queues.

Earning trust based on your contributions by design should cost energy. That this trust should somehow come for free of should be artificially inflated to act as a motivator is just pushing the wrong levers. SE optimizes for quality content. That takes effort from a lot of people, not only the ones creating that content. Making it easy / reward the wrong behavior / mindset does a disservice to the current knowledge base we are, its visitors we attract today and the many contributors that made this place over the last 6 to 8 years.

The initial reputation is 1. Everybody starts there. With the right motivation it is no effort at all to get at a point where you are seen as a trusted member. The system works, it is fine as it is.