# When someone upvotes your question, do you vote/accept their answer more?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette, up-votes, psychology

Not everyone [upvotes questions they answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19470/do-you-ever-not-upvote-a-question-that-you-answer).

On quiet questions, it's easy to tell how the user who answers has (not) voted on the question. Do your reactions to an answer vary when you can tell that the answerer has (not) upvoted your question? If they do, are the reasons intrinsic in how answers are written, or in a "prejudice" on the answerer's intentions?

In my observations, people are more likely to "return" an upvote to my answer if I have upvoted their question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't do this at all. I admit when I have a feeling one of the answerers upvoted my question, I think different about the person who answered. This isn't affecting my look on finding a high-quality right answer.

If there are like multiple answers with the same solution, I first look at the explanations of the answers and then at the time the answers are posted.

Comment: Let's hope everyone is perfectly rational like you when assessing questions, then. :)