# Disable "don't forget to vote" message

Tags: feature-request, notification-bar

Now whenever I get to a SE answer from Google, the site yells at me:

> **Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.**

Is there a way to disable it? I'm quite aware of how to vote on questions and answers and it's annoying to see it every time I click on questions (sometimes many times in a day). Perhaps this could go along with some rep requirement. At least have an option to only nag me once a week or something like that?

Comment: It will go away when you gain sufficient rep on whatever site is displaying this message (I think it's about 200).

Comment: Oh, that's strange. I know I saw it on SO earlier even though I have 7000+ rep, but I can't reproduce it now.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[image]

This message:

> Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.

Only appears if:

- you haven't been seen on the target site for 48 hours, and
- you hold a valid user cookie on the target site, and
- your account has more than 15 rep on the target site, and
- you arrive on a question from a search engine, and
- you have not already voted on this particular question and answers

Therefore, you shouldn't ever see it more than once every 2 days per site. Also, if you are on the target site(s) frequently enough, you may never see it.

Comment: But what if all the answers are major suck? Leading the witness!

Comment: So we can't have any option to get rid of the message? (I do vote up good answers that I find, I promise!)

Comment: @ben you really shouldn't be seeing it that much. Can you describe a little bit more about when you see it and where?

Comment: @JeffAtwood I think I saw it three times today (on SO, SU, and WebApps) and it just seemed a little obnoxious. (Actually, I find all of the notification bar things somewhat annoying when they pop up over the top of the page; they'd be less annoying if (1) they loaded with the page and didn't animate in and (2) they didn't appear on top of the usual header and instead pushed the rest of the page down.)

Comment: @random: There's always the opposite of up...

Comment: There ain't no sideways unless you're doohickeying up your machine and UI experience @and

Comment: Any stats on how much this message improves voting?

Comment: In my view, once-per-day is far too often. Once per week would be better; and an option to permanently disable it would be better still.

I've upvoted many things on stack overflow; I know why it's important. I'm not going to forget about it any time soon. So to be told about it every time I visit the site is ... well lets just say I find it very annoying. If the only way to avoid it is to stay logged out, that would be a shame.

Ideally it should only remind people who have forgotten. That might be difficult to guess, but I suspect there are better indicators than just 24h of not visiting.

Comment: I see it on almost every visit to any stackexchange site, since I don't spend all my time on just one. That's several popups a day.

Comment: I agree with @David on this. Any chance to make it global across the network? I have been quite annoyed by this lately and thinking of staying logged out just to solve this.

Comment: Every day is too often. Maybe it should be turned off after you've seen it 100 times or something. Reminders of etiquette are great, but when they become more annoying than the behavior they're trying to promote/discourage, they should be discontinued.

Comment: Agree w/ David. I see it all the damn time b/c there are now a trillion different stackexchange sites. It's like playing whack-a-mole.

Comment: I see it every day, multiple times a day. I'm always logged in. I often upvote questions/answers/comments. I never want to see this reminder again in my life.

Comment: Pretty sure that the current algorithm is flawed. IMHO, you should be considering how many past upvotes the logged-in user has performed and have a dont-annoy-this-loyal-user threshold.

I'm on StackOverflow a LOT, and I upvote literally every useful question and answer that has helped me, but I still get spammed. You guys now have a Machine Learning Ph.D. in-house, right? Why don't you add a "I find this reminder annoying" button, too, and let him / her derive a classification model (decision tree would be ideal here) to predict who finds it annoying, and use that to re-calibrate the rules.

Comment: Sounds like something is broken with your browser @vijucat as you can plainly read above "only appears if you haven't been seen on the the target site for 24 hours"

Comment: @jeff-atwood, firstly, excuse the rant. I'm not proud of my original reply. Let me try to be more useful : 24 hours is too low. I suspect that "once an upvoter, always an upvoter". In which case, the reminder feels like unnecessary nagging. Maybe you can use a more behavior-based threshold (rather than time-based), such as "Logged-in User is viewing Q&A, but has not upvoted even one out of the past 3"? Trust me : I love StackOverflow and I'd upvote anyway. My real problem is that I Star too many questions.

Comment: @JeffAtwood You keep saying "it shouldn't appear that often". Setting aside the question of how often is acceptable (for me, never), the issue is that it appears separately on every StackExchange site, of which there are hundreds. That easily makes it appear five times a day if you browse multiple sites. I think we can all agree this is too frequent.

Comment: I can't believe this is the accepted answer... It's not your job to give the reader a sermon. And it doesn't even answer the question!

Comment: This has turned the StackExchange experience from "useful content with simple design" to "great, another annoying pop-up every time I visit". I am logged-in on all the sites I use but I frequently Google for answers that are across various sites, so I end up with this pop-up many times per day.  **Please make this a single cross-network pop-up** that is shown at most once a week - otherwise I will just have to use an ad-blocker to suppress it on every site.

Comment: I thought this was a new feature - for some reason, I have only started seeing this in the last few weeks.  Still using Chrome on Mac, so perhaps there's a behaviour change in Chrome - I have noticed it occasionally seems to forget cookies.

Comment: It seems that the duration was recently increased from 24 to 48 hours which is already good but I think still far too frequent.  Wouldn't something like every 2 weeks or so be enough?  Also, it would be great if the "has already seen it"-flag would work network-wide (so that I don't see that banner on superusers.com if I already had it on stackoverflow.com earlier that day).

Comment: Or maybe a better idea: Instead of "haven't been seen on the target site for x hours" how about "haven't been voting for x hours".  By this it would be much more targeted to the people who actually do forget to vote.  Again, this should ideally be network-wide and not per site.

Answer (score 39):

I get this message also on sites where I just registered to be able to vote. I find the message [counterproductive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/154961/160144).

Using the Stylus Firefox/Chrome extension you can disable it this way (replace/add the domain names of your choice):

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("askubuntu.com"),
               domain('superuser.com'),
               domain('serverfault.com')
{
    #overlay-header {display:none !important;}
}
```

One suggestion for improvement: don't show this message to someone who has a Civic Duty badge on any other site. They know about voting...

Comment: "don't show this message to someone who has a Civic Duty badge on any other site"
>This is a great suggestion!

Comment: The only actual solution. It works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: I'm seeing reports that Stylish has turned into malware/history tracking, and the ratings on the addons page is pretty poor. Is there a current alternative?

Comment: @donutguy640 you are right. I replaced it with stylus (https://github.com/openstyles/stylus)

Answer (score 9):

You can block the element in Adblock/uBlock by adding this to your adblocker's filters:

```
askubuntu.com###overlay-header
serverfault.com###overlay-header
stackexchange.com###overlay-header
stackoverflow.com###overlay-header
superuser.com###overlay-header
```

You can be sure you have all of them by generating the file "se.txt" with this Python script:

```py
import json
import requests

response = requests.get(
    "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites#filter=!SmNnfYtt-R(6Wq2POT")
data = response.json()

sites = set()
ht = len("https://")
for site in data["items"]:
    url = site["site_url"]
    sites.add(".".join(url[ht:].rsplit(".", 2)[-2:]))

with open("se.txt", "wt") as f:
    for site in sorted(sites):
        print(f"{site}###overlay-header")
        f.write(f"{site}###overlay-header\n")
```

Comment: Oh, this is even better than the answer with the config for Stylus!

Answer (score 8):

They address why this even happens on [Stack Exchange Podcast #2](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/se-podcast-02/) as a way to remind people to upvote useful and helpful questions:

> Jeff Atwood:
> Now, one thing we have done to help with this is if you come through a web search engine and you arrive on say Stack Over, or Server Fault or any Stack Exchange site, and you actually hold a cookie for that account, meaning you have an account on the site and you are able to vote, we will gently remind you, "Hey! You arrived here through a Google web search. If you found this question useful, please vote it up and the answer."
> **Podcast time point: 51:24**

Because, if you found the question through an external search and it's helped you, or it's well written, bump up the question with an upvote.

It helps with their algorithms on what to show regular users. Like the one that is used to float the good questions that deserve more natural attention to the top over the dregs.

> Joel Spolsky:
> Question score will make something more likely to appear on the homepage. So we need to teach people to vote up questions that are well asked.
> **Podcast time point: 48:15**

Comment: One thing to note.  My RSS reader is NOT A SEARCH ENGINE and clicking on questions to see if I can contribute to the answer doesn't mean I think it's a good question (i.e. matched something **I** needed to know.)

Comment: I don't want to be teached. If i bounce right back after two seconds, just consider it a downvote.

Comment: It's not difficult to learn how the site works. The simple fact is I don't vote on a lot of questions because they aren't relevant to my search. This mechanic might be useful at a certain level but the current tuning is overly aggressive.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative for Chrome to tell the big ugly banner to go sod off: [Referer Control](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referer-control/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin?hl=en)

You can import the following site filter string which should block all Stack Exchange sites:

```
[{"id":"defaultAction","val":"dummy","type":"normal","filter":"","is3rd":true},{"id":1403555615182,"val":"http://*.stackexchange.com/","type":"normal","filter":"","isregexp":false,"isfrom":false,"isto":true,"is3rd":true},{"id":1403555648816,"val":"http://stackoverflow.com/","type":"normal","filter":"","isregexp":false,"isfrom":false,"isto":true,"is3rd":true},{"id":1403555658762,"val":"http://superuser.com/","type":"normal","filter":"","isregexp":false,"isfrom":false,"isto":true,"is3rd":true},{"id":1403555691289,"val":"http://serverfault.com/","type":"normal","filter":"","isregexp":false,"isfrom":false},{"id":1403555708104,"val":"","type":"normal","filter":"","isregexp":false}]
```

Answer (score 3):

The userscript [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/29559) supports hiding this banner.

[image]

<sup>Report issues: [Remove the welcome back message · Issue #315 · soscripted/sox](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues/315#issuecomment-392529667)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

1. Install https://www.tampermonkey.net (available for Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Safari, Opera Next, and Firefox)

   [image]
2. Go to Dashboard:

   [image]
3. Go to add user script:

   [image]
4. Create the following user script:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Close Stackexchange Up Vote Notifications bar
// @namespace    *
// @version      0.1
// @description  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89045/disable
// @author       You
// https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81379/can-we-have-a-list-of-all
// @include https://*askubuntu.com/*
// @include https://*mathoverflow.net/*
// @include https://*blogoverflow.com/*
// @include https://*serverfault.com/*
// @include https://*stackoverflow.com/*
// @include https://*stackexchange.com/*
// @include https://*stackapps.com/*
// @include https://*stackmod.blog/*
// @include https://*stackoverflow.blog/*
// @include https://*stackoverflowbusiness.com/*
// @include https://*superuser.com/*
// @include https://*tex-talk.net/*
// @include https://*thesffblog.com/*
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
   'use strict';
   let keepclosing = async () => {
       let closebutton = $('#overlay-header');
       if(closebutton.length) {
           console.log('Close Stackexchange Up Vote Notifications bar');
           closebutton.remove();
           setTimeout(keepclosing, 500);
       }
   }
   setTimeout(keepclosing, 500);
})();
```

5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save it:

   [image]
6. Reload your Stack Exchange page and that banner will be automatically closed.

#### Related questions

These related questions are both about removing annoying things from pages. The first removes the GitHub top notifications, which is the same thing as this question about removing the Stack Exchange top (begging) bar. The second is about removing the annoying YouTube viewed videos. This second question uses hide instead of remove due to YouTube page nature. The second question helps as a remainder/example that instead of removing things from the page, you could just hide them.

1. https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/issues/3061 - Automatically close the notification top bar
2. [How to stop the youtube home page from suggesting videos I already saw?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/145612/how-to-stop-the)

Comment: I think those "related" links might run afoul of [self-promotion rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) (mainly the "*Don't include links except to support what you've written*" part). Neither link seems immediately related to this post, and you haven't disclosed that they're yours (the second link definitely is, the first *presumably* is).

Comment: The related questions I added are about code examples of removing things from pages. Motivating the reader to think out of the box reason for someone trying to solve a similar problem. As this question uses a program/script, I am trying to give related problems which could help other programmers to solve their problem. I could directly explain things and copy-paste that code into this answer, but just linking them should be enough. I updated the question with some more reasoning about the related links.