# Please Stop the 'questions need votes too' pop-up, it's becoming VERY annoying

Tags: discussion, voting, popups

I see that we're trying to 'remind' folks to vote on questions by doing a small pop-up whenever we vote up answers (presumably this is only for folks like me who haven't voted up a question in a while).

Can we please find some less-annoying way to do this? Perhaps one of those page head banners when I open the site? The pop-up when voting on answers is EXTREMELY annoying and I'd really like it to stop.

I understand the desire to motivate people to vote on questions, but I've always felt that SO & friends have done well with 'making the right thing easy' rather than 'beating the users until they do what we want'. Don't change that focus now, please.

Updated: since some folks find the banners more annoying than the pop-ups, perhaps a message in the inbox for folks who haven't voted up a question in a while? I don't necessarily care how the reminder is issued, I just want it to NOT be the pop-up!

Comment: I hate banners even more than I do popups.

Comment: +1 Good question, don't forget to vote this up!

Comment: Upvote some questions, stingy.  I'd suggest looking on my account for awesome questions to upvote.

Comment: +1 for irony. No, actually, you've got a point with `'making the right thing easy' rather than 'beating the users until they do what we want'`. But I don't have any better ideas than what's being done here. Do *you?*

Comment: @Justin Morgan - honestly, I'm all for posting it to my Inbox. Daily or weekly, if need be. Just not a pop-up. Again, nothing against some kind of reminder, just NOT a freaking pop-up!

Comment: Simple solution, vote on some questions.

Comment: +1, getting annoyed loading the site from a google search and getting a "welcome back! you should upvote if you find this useful!".. I know..

Comment: I'd be happier if someone could tell me *why* I should vote for questions. Voting for answers makes sense, they were helpful, voting for questions though? WTF? Some questions should be voted down but what makes a "good question"? I feel like I'd be voting everything up and then my profile is full of questions I've voted up — which I don't want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable "don't forget to vote" message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89059/282094)

Answer (score 23):

I've yet to see the pop-up in question on any site... And based on my own analysis, I'm pretty sure that my votes are disproportionately cast on answers as compared to questions. It can't be *that* frequent.

I think the key lies in the fact that you hardly ever cast any votes. There's a live counter on our user profiles now; here's what [yours](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5801/michael-kohne) has to report:

[image: 2 votes cast this month, 2 votes cast this week, 2 votes cast today]

You've only voted twice all month! I realize you say that you'd prefer the team didn't adopt the "beating the users until they do what we want" philosophy, but I don't think it'd kill you to cast a few more votes. You'll probably start seeing a lot less pop-ups, too, as the system will realize you know what you're doing.

Comment: True, I have not participated much in SO lately - I've been doing other things (yes, I have a life AWAY from the computer!). And this morning, when I did have time to participate, I found myself being beaten because I wasn't participating enough. I'm not saying that some sort of reminder isn't a good idea, but I am saying that this reminder is a blasted nuisance that's just causing me to want to not vote at all, rather than do what I'm told. And try to remember that I'm here because I want to help. Beating on me because I don't help as much as you do right now is entirely inappropriate.

Comment: This answer is *exactly* what the user means.  There's nothing wrong with his participation at SO, it is close to exemplary.  Berating it is not appropriate.

Comment: Hmm, my goal in writing this answer was to provide an explanation for the behavior, and in what I thought was a somewhat light-hearted way, suggest a possible fix. I'm not really sure now how it got misinterpreted as "berating" or "beating on" anyone; that certainly wasn't my intention. I didn't implement the feature in the first place, so if you're really angry about it, you're probably barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 15):

[image: hmmm]

I understand why you find this annoying, it seems, you rarely if ever vote on questions. We have found that **only** voting on answers is very problematic cause it makes it very hard for us to surface good questions and bury bad ones.

The message is there for outliers who barely if ever vote on questions, and is designed to shape behavior. I get that it is annoying, however the vast majority of the people are happy with this change.

If this topic gains lots of momentum and say has 20 question votes, we will consider something else.

Comment: Wait, you **aren't** gonna change the system because of one outlier? `;)`

Comment: Hmmmm. How does he have *less* votes cast on Stack Overflow now than when I took the same screenshot for my answer? He had 383 then, now only 365. My math fails me most of the time, but I'm pretty sure that's less.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Maybe the vote counts were denormalized, and now recalculated to show the more detailed statistics? Then it would remove all votes for posts that were deleted.

Comment: @Cody ... I have no idea ... my guess would be a bunch of stuff got deleted

Comment: You instantly lowered the vote counts by ~10% for just about everybody I think.  It's not heading the right way :)

Comment: I would vote on this question but that's what The Man wants me to do, and I'm a rebel.

Answer (score 14):

I only occasionally get the pop-up and it does exactly what it is meant to do: reminds me to vote on questions. Damn good idea, as I do forget sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely unrelated to the counter *(mine shown below).*

Despite my counter, I got the reminder, though just the once, after some time away from SE.

> [image]