# "Vote for questions" nagging is making it less likely that I'll vote for answers

Tags: discussion, voting

This morning, every time I've voted for an answer, I've gotten a popup telling I haven't voted for a question recently.  Since that's an extra click to dismiss, and since I haven't seen a question worth voting up recently, my first reaction is to stop voting on answers rather than go on an extensive hunt for questions worth voting up.

Please make this popup less obtrusive.  Either make it fade away quickly on its own without being clicked on, or make it only show up every n'th answer vote.

Update: Ok, it does fade away on its own, just slower than I expected.

Comment: This is not a bug - please change to either Feature Request or Discussion.

Comment: "...and since I haven't seen a question worth **voting up** recently..." - if they're all that bad then why don't you vote some of them *down*? Do you know it's now [free to downvote questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free/90927#90927)? So, when you do see any bad questions then please give them the downvote they deserve.

Comment: Because there is a difference between a question deserving of a downvote and a question not deserving of any vote at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please Stop the 'questions need votes too' pop-up, it's becoming VERY annoying.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90109/please-stop-the-questions-need-votes-too-pop-up-its-becoming-very-annoying)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only get the message is you are voting a lot on answers only.

Try voting on questions, if a question creates an answer worth voting up, then the question might be worth an upvote as well.

Also, if all you see is bad questions, then please downvote them.