# Reduce frequency of "go vote on a question" reminder

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, voting, popups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please Stop the 'questions need votes too' pop-up, it's becoming VERY annoying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90109/please-stop-the-questions-need-votes-too-pop-up-its-becoming-very-annoying)

Recently every time I vote on an answer at meta.math, I get a yellow pop-up saying that I have only been voting on answers recently, and questions should be voted on to.

Generally I do not object to such gentle reminders. I agree that telling people to vote more on questions/answers will promote healthier voting habits.

But does the pop-up really need to come up every single time I vote? If I ignored a pop-up just 10 seconds ago, chances are I'll ignore it again now! Having nag-screen/pop-ups come up too often will just train the users to ignore them.

Comment: As soon as you vote on a question, you will have tranquility for about 15 answer votes (if I remember right).

Comment: +1 This especially irritates me since about 45% of my lifetime votes are on questions. If I happen to spend a day mostly voting on answers, I don't need to be reminded about question votes with every one cast.

Comment: Do you ever, you know, **vote on questions**? I still haven't seen this pop-up yet.

Comment: @Cody: my vote breakdown for meta.math is 93 questions, 243 answers. That is much much higher than the 1:15 mentioned in @Paulo's comment. Like Josh said, the algorithm does not seem to be based on long-term trends!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *intended* to be a tiny bit annoying, and voting on questions is quite painless.

However, I can see your point, and I'm a big fan of [intermittent, variable reinforcement](http://headrush.typepad.com/creating_passionate_users/2006/03/clicker_trained.html), so …

```
var r = new Random();
if (r.Next(0, 2) == 0)
{
    message = "you haven't voted on questions in a while;<br>questions need votes too!";
}
```