# It takes two clicks on the X to close a flag-submitted popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, popups

It takes two clicks on the X to close a flag-submitted popup

Tested without extensions, on Firefox. I couldn't find similar reports.

> [image]

Comment: Reproduced using FF on Mac, appears that the banner is there twice...

Comment: You have to double click to  prevent accidental closing, so [tag:status-bydesign] ...

Comment: @rene got any source for that? I find that a very dubious decission, as it will also just time-out on itself.

Comment: @rene: What are the chances of moving the cursor up, aiming, and clicking, for it to be accidental? 

Comment: I'm not the UX expert, so beats me ;)

Comment: I'm looking into this now! Was able to repro it on Safari as well, seems like there are definitely two 'thank you's popping up. Thanks for the report, will report back once it's fixed.

Comment: @kristinalustig: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it also affects the *vote on questions* reminder. And thanks!

Comment: @ymb1 can you be more specific about which reminder you're referring to? (our codebase is so big, searching exact text of a reminder like that is the easiest way to find it :-| )

Comment: @kristinalustig: It's called [questions need votes too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90109/392799), according to the linked post ←. I don't remember the exact verbatim.

Comment: Also reproducable in chrome on android.

Comment: Voting to close does not exhibit the same behaviour

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for your report! I've fixed this - we were indeed calling this popup twice in the javascript for what seemed to be ...legacy reasons? Which is shorthand for "We couldn't find any place in the code where it made sense for this to be called in two separate places but probably somebody did it for a reason at some point." The fix will be in for the next build, coming today or tomorrow.