# I filled out a survey and now the system is thanking me all the time

Tags: bug, notification-bar, stack-overflow-developer-survey

I've just finished answering [this survey](https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_b14eaLcRaiLlZMF), and now every time I go to some page at [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), it shows me this banner:

[image]

It happens for every single page I visit on SOpt (main and meta). It doesn't happen here in MSE.

I'm always clicking the <kbd>x</kbd> to close it, but it keeps showing the message, everytime I go to another page or reload the current one.

The only pages where this doesn't happen are the review queues, but only if I'm in a specific queue: so at `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/`, the problem occurs, but if I'm at some queue (such as `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/` or `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts`), the problem doesn't occur.

I know this survey must be important and so on, but thanking me just once is enough. Can this be fixed please?

---

I'm using Windows 10 Home 64 bits, Chrome 89.0.4389.82.

Comment: The site is just extremely gratefull to you today

Comment: as a side note, thank you for filling out the satisfaction survey!

Comment: I ran the survey through the link you provided, I only got the notification once.

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361967/it-takes-two-clicks-on-the-x-to-close-a-flag-submitted-popup

Comment: I see a bug: not enough 

Comment: so they do exist

Comment: Text [Improvement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prrs6.png).

Comment: Gives a whole new meaning to "Thanks a million".

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature of the welcome bandwagon.

Comment: You might be blocking third party cookies, try to enable them, run the survey again if possible, and see if the problem still happens.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating I've checked Chrome cookie settings and it's set to "*Block third party cookies __in Incognito__*" - but I didn't use an incognito window to fill out the survey. Actually, there are 2 cookies from qualtrics.com here (so I guess it didn't block anything from the survey)

Comment: And now it's not happening anymore - I didn't do anything in my browser/OS

Comment: I would love that to happen to me: did you enable/disable any userscripts to make it not happen? I filled out the survey and it isn't thanking me thatmuch.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Here we go again, asking users to lower their security/privacy settings instead of investigating and fixing the problem at the source. I was hoping that this practice died a few years ago. Apparently not.

Comment: @BrianDrake obviously only for the purpose of testing this issue then setting it back to whatever it was before. Default setting is to not block, so if someone changed it they are well aware of the meaning, and I don't need to tell them to set it back after they test if that's the issue.

Comment: @10Rep I have a userscript to revert line-height and blockquotes layout, but that's all. Anyway, I didn't disabled them, the problem was happening with them enabled, and they were still enabled when it stopped happening. As I said in my previous comment, I didn't change anything, I was just browsing the site and noticed that it wasn't happening anymore.