# I see "Welcome back! If you found this question useful..." message very frequently

Tags: support, search-engine

For the past few weeks, almost every time I link directly from Google into a question I see the banner:

> Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.

I've clicked the "hide" link at the bottom of that banner.  It will seem to keep it hidden for a little while (in other words, for the next few questions I click into), but then it will show up again a day or two later.  This seems like a bug...

Comment: An additional annoying behavior of this is that if you do click to hide it and then click a link within an answer that brings you to another website, when you hit your browser "Back" button to return to the question, the popup will appear again, doubling your frustration.

Comment: It is a friendly greeting to me, so I do not mind it, actually.

Comment: I am annoyed by this message since so long ago that I have long forgotten that it is about voting... So I don't read it before closing, obviously.

Comment: Because they never solved this massively annoying issue, I had to activate Ublock Origin on stack exchange to block these pop ups, thus I also don't watch the ads anymore. I hope this makes them take us more seriously.

Comment: I cannot believe it's been 9 years and Stack has done nothign about it. :(

Comment: Irony is that popup does not auto go away even when I do vote on the question ;-(

Answer (score 96):

The current criteria for choosing when to show the banner are IMHO overly aggressive and will only get worse as Stack Exchange grows. I frequent two or three Stack Exchange sites, but I visit many of the others infrequently.  I prefer them to other Q&A sites, because I know they work. But every time I go to a specific Stack Exchange site that I haven't been to recently enough for the current criteria, I get this message.

The message detracts from my experience because:

- It is visually distracting (deliberately because it's animated)
- I can't just ignore it, because it covers up useful UI elements
- It forces me to do extra work to make it go away
- It tells me nothing I didn't already know

**Suggested improvement:**
I suggest the current criteria be expanded to include a condition that checks your frequency of activity across all Stack Exchange sites.  "Activity" can include voting not just visiting, and then the message will get to the right people. Clearly targeting this message at people who already vote frequently is unnecessary.

Those of us who are frequent users of the system-at-large, but not that specific site, shouldn't have to put up with this. To be clear, this is making Stack Exchange worse for me, and the impact is increasing as the number of Stack Exchange sites increases.

Comment: still don't agree, I get this reminder a fair bit these days, and I think it is *completely* fair to remind me to vote on questions / answers I get to via search. If they were useful enough to show up in my results, I owe them at least that.

Comment: @Jeff, I'm frankly shocked that your suggested work-around is to log out if I use Google a lot.  Srsly?  You want to encourage people to log out?

Comment: I still cannot believe that this message appears in random SE sites even if you have thousands of rep in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think this is annoying as well, especially if you just want to use the search function.

Comment: @JeffAtwood the problem is there are **a lot** of SE sites. So the frequency of seeing the popup is multiplied 20x times for active users like me, as I am a member of 20+ SE sites. In addition, I am not an idiot and don't need to be reminded to vote on questions / answers as I've been doing that on a daily basis for the last 7 years.

Answer (score 28):

I think this is feasible.

Unlike Jeff Atwood, who suggests loading the pop-up if you have more than 15 rep at the target site but haven't visited the site for 72 hours (and more), I suggest limiting this to user that:

- Haven't visited the site for one week
- Have more than 15 rep at the target site and have no accounts with at least 500 rep
- Haven't created a positive contribution to  SE (any SE site) for a total of 100 unique days

The period has been extended since 3 days without activity isn't really *that* long. 7 days though is a clear indicator of inactivity. Responding to the comments relating to having thousands of rep and still being reminded, the pop-up only shows up for the less-experienced users, those with less than 500 rep on any site. And to ensure you understand SE well and not have a single answer racking up tons of rep, you need to do something at SE that proves that you understand SE... for 100 total days (100 days total SE-wide).

A positive contribution will clearly vary upon users... Anyways, this should cover two key points mentioned by Jeff Atwood and/or the comments:

- Lack of activity for an extended lack of time means that you are slowly losing your knowledge of the site and not as up to date
- These reminders don't need to be mentioned to experienced users who know the drill

Comment: "Jeff Atwood -- if more than 15 rep but haven't visited for 72 hours".  The pop-up is a reminder to vote on questions. I literally vote 100% of the time. I should never see this regardless of my rep, hours away, or any other metric that is not "does this person ever vote?" It is an utterly useless UI element (to people already voting all the time) intended to help people who forget, and I bet the internal metrics show it works (on average), but it annoys everyone who already does The Right Thing. Can Stack Exchange please also do The Right Thing?

Comment: Chiming in about the comment "the pop-up only shows up for the less-experienced users, those with less than 500 rep on any site", this is not true currently.  I hit this popup constantly, even on sites where I have rep far in excess of that number.

Answer (score 11):

Installing [Referer Control extension for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referer-control/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin?hl=en) helped to get rid of this annoying messages.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use this extension to block this designed annoyance?

Comment: You set up this extension so that it blocks referer headers for stackoverflow.com and others.

Comment: I just need to install or is there some configuration needed?

Comment: You click on the extension icon to open its configuration. You need to configure what to do with `referer` header on sites you want.

Answer (score -3):

This isn't a bug, this is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89045/disable-dont-forget-to-vote-message/89059#89059):

> Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.

only appears if all of the following are true:

- you haven't been seen on the target site for 48 hours
- you hold a valid user cookie on the target site
- your account has more than 15 rep on the target site
- you arrive on a question from a search engine
- you have not already voted on this particular question and answers

If you are a very infrequent visitor, yet tend to hit a lot of web search results... you might want to log out. **But you really should be voting up all those search results if you found them, and they are helping you!**

Comment: I assume you have metrics in place to measure the effectiveness of this prompt? I wonder if you can evaluate the need for the message at runtime so that you don't annoy chronic searchers if they meet some minimum threshold for voting on answers they find. For example, if they vote on *n out of 10* questions, perhaps they can hide the message. If their voting patterns change and they only vote on *m out of 10*, you override their "hide" preference.

Comment: Jeff - I am honored to be rebutted by you.  Still, I feel this prompt ends up being annoying noise after a while... It definitely is no longer encouraging me to vote up good questions.  Anyway, thanks. hearts and unicorns...

Comment: ...and as I think about it a bit longer, possibly the problem is that it comes up before I've had a chance to even read the question and answers, so I don't know yet.  It's a bit like the salesguy that harasses you as soon as you walk into the store instead of after you've had a chance to look around and get your bearings.  Maybe it could show up after a minute or something?  Or possibly after I vote up an answer?

Comment: @Joe, why should the system remind you to vote *after you've already done so?*

Comment: @Anthony - the reminder I'm complaining about is a reminder to vote for the _Question_.  I am suggesting that this reminder be shown when a user votes for an _Answer_ (since this indicates they found the general topic of the question useful, useful enough to evaluate and vote for an answer).

Comment: Oh, right. Very well then, carry on.

Comment: I've used SO for quite a while now, I know how it works. A message bugging me to vote is annoying and won't affect if I vote that question or answer up. The vast majority of questions I find via Google don't apply to what I'm searching for. If I find a question/answer that helped me or that I find useful/good I'll vote for it, no worries, but that message is annoying!

Comment: As a long time StackOverflow user, this message popup annoys me to distraction, to the point that I've STOPPED VOTING UP THE GOOD QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS out of annoyance.   This is very useless, what, because I haven't visited in 24 hours?   Why not display if I haven't visited in one hour?   Why not have a floating CSS popup that keeps the annoying message up for the entire duration of a visit?

Comment: 24 hours seems like *way* too short a time period.  It's not like I've forgotten how the site works merely because I was competent enough yesterday to avoid SO for any help. :)  It's also more annoying because the message is multi-line - I can't just ignore it easily, like I can with the other notifications.

Comment: I also have to take issue with "If you are a very infrequent visitor, yet tend to hit a lot of web search results... you might want to log out.".  If I was an infrequent visitor, I wouldn't mind - clicking away a banner every few weeks isn't a big deal.  It's precisely because I visit every other day or so that it's annoying, and the only thing it motivates me to do is stay logged-out (thus, not voting up any questions or answers).  I think the root of the problem may be our differing expectations of usage of the site - you seem to think that we should all be visiting multiple times a day.

Comment: @xiong fine; I increased it to 48 hours. This will go out in the next deploy.

Comment: Personally, Jeff, I really think this should be more like every 5-10 days, definitely *not* every 48 hours. We're smart people here, we know how the site works, and we know that we can (and should) upvote questions. We don't need to be hounded by a digital mother to do our chores. Would it be so bad if it only popped up once a week? Or only if I haven't upvoted a question for a while? Or maybe only if I have viewed X number of questions without voting? Or maybe just trust that the smart people that use your site, don't need reminding every other day.

Comment: I'm reminded of an article about Joel Spolsky (I think you know him) about little things adding up. In the big scheme of things, this reminder is definitely not a huge deal, but it definitely qualifies as an annoyance (a rather large one to boot).  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000057.html

Comment: @kogi fine; I increased it to 72 hours. If this is still an issue, well.. once every 3 days doesn't seem all that onerous to me.

Comment: 72 is certainly better, but it's still... well, I run into this fairly frequently.  Part of it, I think, is that I do a lot of different things; so, unless I'm mistaken, if I visit StackOverflow today I can still get the message on ServerFault tomorrow.  I haven't paid enough attention to say if this is truly the case, so I won't press it.

Comment: The fact that it's once every three days isn't what makes it annoying; it's that it seems like it's **every time** I visit the site.  Normally SO and related sites are the first thing I click on if they appear in Google results; this encourages me to either not do so (!) or to log out (which bothers me, because I like upvoting useful things and leaving helpful comments).  I don't mean to sound whiny; I just find it frustrating that something that has made programming *so much better* seems insistent on driving me away from it.

Comment: The logic behind this is that it makes SO better, at the expense of annoying people.  

So, this means we can now post the same question on SO every 72 hours, right?  That way answers to questions will be updated all the time, making SO better - admittedly, at the expense of annoying some people.

Comment: How often do most users visit stackoverflow?  My *guess* is that for most users, including myself, "once every 24 hours" and "once every 72 hours" both translate to "every time I visit stackoverflow."  For us, this change is not a change.

Comment: To break out of the ongoing dialog of "is this timeperiod long enough?" I've offered a concrete suggestion for a change that I think can address everybody's concerns.  See my alternate answer on this question.

Comment: Why not at least make it go away forever after 10 or 20 votes?

Comment: My feelings about these popups: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5d5jxJ5vbM&t=0m12s

Comment: The message also appears regardless of whether you can actually upvote the question/answers. If you are viewing a closed question, the message is misleading.

Comment: Can you please stop torturing us with this message? It drives me nuts

Comment: @JeffAtwood Please disable the message for anyone who has voted on questions 100 times among all StackExchange sites. I love StackExchange but this one single item is, as Santropedro says, driving me nuts.  And it isn't just once every 3 days.  If I close the message, navigate, press back, then it reappears.  At the very least fix that.

Comment: This feature should be tied to your activity across the the Stack Exchange network. If I've been on Stack Overflow recently and visit Server Overflow, I should not see that message. Better still, my high rep/number of votes should be factored in to how long until a prompt is necessary.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I have the exact same problem as this question, and seeing as this has been a problem since 2011 I'm not going to hope this will get fixed anytime soon. I would not mind if the popup appears after 30 seconds or so, but right now it's just harrassing me to upvote, which I already very well know to do. So, I've decided to turn back on my adblocker for SE sites, although I would rather not do that. I love these sites but this banner popping up every 48 hours, for each of SE's websites, is just too spammy. I'll be checking occasionally if SE stops harrassing users.

Comment: "But you really should be voting up all those search results if you found them, and they are helping you!" That doesn't stop the banner coming up! I visit DBA infrequently, but I know how to use SE. I will vote up questions that help me, and not those that don't. The banner is just a nuisance.

Comment: For anyone looking for a workaround, add a filter on '###overlay-header' in uBlock Origin.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but I find the emphasis on voting for questions that are helpful wrong. People ask questions on S.O. with the aim of obtaining help, which is reward in itself. Answering questions to the high standard demanded by SO is far more deserving of the almost equal value of upvotes.

Comment: Chiming in a decade+ later to add to the chorus that this is an incredibly annoying feature. I hope there is never anything useful in the `overlay-header` element because I've blocked it everywhere. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: gosh, the message is so annoying... on desktop it can be blocked by ad-blockers, but on mobile it is much harder..

Comment: my opinion on this has not changed. If anything it has hardened. I hit SE sites in my search results and I realize, I **the founder of the site** have forgotten to upvote the things that were helpful to me. So the reminder serves a purpose, and matches my lived experience. Now, if you are on sites extremely frequently, maybe. But for very infrequent  hits which is where I am today, it's the right design, and always has been.

Comment: I automatically click it away when it pops up, it does not remind me to anything since I even don't look at it anymore. It is just anyoing and useless, please remove that banner. As you can on the votes and comments, other people think the same about it.