# The "don't forget to vote" message should not be telling me to upvote answers if I found the question useful

Tags: feature-request, voting, wording, notification-bar

So there is [this message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289239/390967) that I saw for the first time today that says:

> Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote
>   both the question and the answers up.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of message]

This message asks me to upvote the question **and the answers** if the question is useful. But a question's usefulness does not necessarily have any correlation to an answer's usefulness. People should be upvoting answers if **the answers** are useful.

This message should thus be changed to either only ask me to upvote the question, or to mention finding **both the question and the answers** useful.

Comment: I suggest: If you find **either** the question or answer helpful, don't forget to up-vote them.

Comment: I might suggest simply: "If you found this useful".

Comment: My suggestion: "Welcome back! Don't forget you can upvote the question and its answers if you find them useful."