# Is it possible to disable the Welcome Back banner?

Tags: support, status-deferred, notification-bar

I have been a Stack Exchange member for over 6 years, with accounts on over 90 sites. I have several thousand total rep. I've seen the "Welcome Back" banner hundreds of times and clicked "close this message" almost as many times.

At this point the banner is completely and utterly useless. It doesn't remind me of anything because I stopped reading it after about the 3rd appearance. Its sole purpose these days is to cover the buttons at the top of the page and waste my time.

Is there any way to permanently disable it?

Comment: It's also completely inconsistent with the new Stacks design. The design has been completely unchanged since it was implemented by Jeff Atwood in 2010-11.

Comment: What is the solution for this issue?

Comment: If you use Adblock Plus, you can manually disable it. I've done that with the 'Welcome' banner for communities I don't have an account for.

Comment: @marcellothearcane That's a good point. I might do that, thanks.

Comment: This has been annoying users for almost 10 years: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91553/185171