# Why does the "welcome back" banner appear on almost every question?

Tags: feature-request, notification-bar, focus

### Context

I really often vote on questions and answers. I really do. I don't if I read it partially or so.

But I keep seeing this annoying banner even if I see a given question for the first time.

[image: Banner]

It says "Welcome back!", but I am not back on this question. It's like another cookie warning. It is simply distractive.

### Questions

1. Why is the banner so intrusive?
2. Is there any logic behind that decides when I see it? Could it be tuned to show the banner less often?

### Feature Request

Allow to disable that banner completely in the account settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to disable the Welcome Back banner?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344261/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-welcome-back-banner)  It's [tag:status-review] and tagged FR.

Comment: There most likely will be logic behind this, but that is more a support question then a FR. Seeing that you don't objectively state what happens when, its hard to judge if there is something wrong here. How often do you see this banner. How long is there usually between your site visits? I am a fairly active user of MSE, and only ocasionally spot this banner on other sites in the network.

Comment: Well, yes, thank you @Ollie I see it's 10 years long battle. I should simply log out. Not sure if it's the intended outcome of this banner... ;)

Comment: @hans Most things do have unintended consequences, especially where popups (*ahem*, cookie banner, *ahem*) are concerned.