# Display "Welcome back! If you found this question useful" message only to certain users who don't vote?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, user-experience, user-information

I vote very often on questions and answers, yet I still see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91553/i-see-welcome-back-if-you-found-this-question-useful-message-very-frequent) message extremely frequently.

Is there any option to either

1. Turn it off permanently, or
2. Perhaps have it displayed more intelligently (e.g. if a user doesn't vote often, hasn't been reminded in the past month, and hasn't been reminded > 100 times before)? or
3. If it must appear, have it push the rest of the page down (rather than blocking existing page elements)

If those options aren't possible, are there any clever hacks (along the lines of pop up blockers) that can help those who *really* don't want it?

#### Update

Just to bolster the case, here I've literally clicked the upvote button, but the loading of the "Welcome back! If you found this question useful" message meant the upvote didn't register. It literally prevented the thing it was trying to encourage.

[image]