# Can we please not show the "Please vote up" bar when a user is already logged in?

Tags: feature-request, voting, notification-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable “don't forget to vote” message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89045/disable-dont-forget-to-vote-message)

I mean really, I have enough reputation on SO to know that I should vote up and the bar is large enough that I can't check how many messages I have without closing the stupid reminder.

I know this is a good move in general, I'm not disputing that, but the site already has to know whether I'm logged in or not so I feel like it would be possible to say something like, 'if you have over 150 reputation you don't need to see this reminder every time'

Thank you,
Chuck Vose

Comment: Thank you Shog, initial search didn't show me that answer so I appreciate the redirect.