# People with high enough reputation should not receive automated behavior suggestions

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, notification-bar, reminder

My reputation in StackOverflow is among the top 1% of users. I'm not as active as I used to be, but I still come back to the site from time to time. Unfortunately, I find that when I *do* return, I get a message "Welcome back, you can upvote!" To be frank, this reminds me of the paperclip on Word 98. I am well aware that I can upvote (or edit comments, or delete posts, or downvote, or undelete posts, or flag, or... pretty much everything)

If reputation could we either get rid of the message entirely or at least get rid of the "you can vote" part of the message?

While I'm at it, I would also appreciate it if a high rep level meant that I could skip the "You've down voted someone! Please add a suggestion to try to make it better." Once again, I am more than aware how the system works, I do not need JavaScript annoying me about it.

Comment: I haven't seen either of those messages since I broke the 1K threshold.  Do you have any screenshots of when this happened?

Comment: Do you mean "Welcome back [username], you've been logged in. Click here to refresh the page." ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hT61p.png))?

Comment: @RobW No. I mean I've gotten "Don't forget you can vote for this."

Comment: @Makoto I will try to remember to get a screen shot next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really there to remind you that you *can* vote. It's there to remind you that you *should* vote. IIRC, the rationale was that folks coming in from searching who aren't using the site otherwise tend to be in a hurry (understandably) and often *do* forget to vote when they find something helpful. The rules for displaying it can be found here: [Disable "don't forget to vote" message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89045/disable-dont-forget-to-vote-message)

The down-vote message already works as you describe - [you shouldn't see it once you've passed 2,000 reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes).

Comment: I must have been using a different account for the down-vote message.

Comment: FWIW, in the two+ years since I wrote this, that message has repeatedly shamed me upon returning to a question that *has* helped me yet which I *hadn't* upvoted.