# How to improve "don't forget to vote" message criteria

Tags: feature-request, notification-bar

[Currently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89059/38765), the basis of "don't forget to vote" is:

- you haven't been seen on the target site for 24 hours
- you hold a valid user cookie on the target site
- your account has more than 15 reputation on the target site
- you arrive on a question from a search engine
- you have not already voted on this particular question and answers

This is mainly annoying to regular users of Stack Exchange - in my case when I occasionally come across Super User while Googling.

I can think of two ways of avoiding annoying the regular users.

One is to change the first criteria to

- You haven't been seen on the Stack Exchange network for 24 hours

Another would be to only show it to people with a low overall Stack Exchange reputation.

Comment: How about show the banner if user has voted less than X times in the last Y days? Shouldn't matter if it's a high-rep or low-rep user...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the simplest criterion would be excluding anyone with 10+ votes in the last month or 30+ total votes on the target site: if someone has voted that many times, he or she has likely got into a habit of voting, so if they choose not to vote, it's not because they "forgot" to do it.