# Banner : Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up

Tags: support, voting

Visited [Super User](https://superuser.com/) today and was welcomed with a banner which read as:

> Welcome back! If you found this question useful,
>   don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up

Snapshot:

[image: superuser]

I was wondering if similar kind of banners are shown to users when they visit https://stackoverflow.com and all other Stack Exchange sites, after a considerable time gap.

Yes, it feels good to be welcomed !!!

So, if the answer is **yes**, what is the minimum time gap?

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89045/369802) is asking about how to disable the welcome back banner, but the answer there also sheds some light on the criteria for when it shows.

Comment: An answer to this question would essentially be repeating Jeff's answer found by Tinkeringbell, even though it's a different question. Feel free to [edit] your question if you think something still isn't covered.

Comment: @Glorfindel I think that's a contradictory statement which includes `different question` and `repeating Jeff's answer`. My question isn't about **disabling** anyway.

Comment: The essential part is 'This question already has an answer here:' (in the banner at the top of this page), which (IMHO) is true. The problem with an answer here is that if the conditions ever change (maybe they already did), **they have to be changed in two places**. Most of us are developers and want to keep [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: BTW I've upvoted your question because I think it's a useful [signpost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324/295232) to have.

Comment: Great !!! But how does that helps me if I don't get an answer to my question?

Comment: @DebanjanB - Except you have received an answer to your question