# Opt out of the "welcome back" banner

Tags: feature-request

There have been a few questions about this already, it seems that whenever you

- haven't been seen on the target site for 24 hours
- hold a valid user cookie on the target site
- have an account with more than 15 rep on the target site
- arrive on a question from a search engine
- have not already voted on this particular question and answers

you get this lovely banner reminding you to vote if you think the content was useful. source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89059/276106

However, I don't see the point in this message. I know how the site works, I don't need it to remind me to vote. In fact, a pushy message like this is only going to make me not vote on things out of spite. It also covers the site's header, and is in general just very distracting. Typically this type of message has a 'dismiss' and a 'don't show again' option, can we get that for this banner too?

Comment: As a workaround, you could add a rule in your adblocker to remove the banner automatically (e.g. like how you can hide the 'new contributor' banner using the instructions in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372880/4622463))